# javascript homework on converting decimal to hex

Tags: javascript

What is the hexadecimal equivalent of number 264<sub>10</sub> and 140<sub>10</sub>? Please give me full coding of this program.

Comment: you should do your hw youself. how will you learn otherwise?

Comment: [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57803/6521116)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [toString function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) on numbers, and pass the base to be converted:

```
(264).toString(16); // 108 hex
(140).toString(16); // 8c  hex
```

And to do the opposite, you can use the [parseInt function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/ParseInt):

```
parseInt('108', 16);  // 264 dec
parseInt('8c', 16);   // 140 dec
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a Homework question, I am guessing that the questioner may be looking for an algorithm.

This is some C# code that does this without special functions:

```
int x = 140;
string s = string.Empty;
while (x != 0)
{
    int hexadecimal = x % 16;
    if (hexadecimal < 10)
         s = hexadecimal.ToString() + s;
    else
         s = ((char)('A' + (char)(hexadecimal - 10))).ToString() + s;
    x = (int)(x / (int)16);
}
MessageBox.Show("0X" + s);
```

Since this is homework, you can figure out how to translate this into JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

264: 0x108

140: 0x8C

No program required.

Comment: Did you do that by hand, or did you use the Calculator applet?

Comment: With the calculator of course. As a programmer I am obviously lazy.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you had better do it programmatically after all.  `s/246/264/`

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't know, you can use Google to convert [decimal to hexadecimal](http://www.google.com/search?q=264+in+hex) or [vice versa](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x108+in+decimal).

But it looks like @CMS already posted the Javascript code for you :) +1 to him.