# Convert opacity to hex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

What would be the preferred way to convert opacity (0 - 1) to hex (00 - ff) in Javascript?

My thoughts are to use an if statement to check if opacity is between 1 and 0.95 then use ff. Work my way down to 0.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert"? Are you talking about changing a colour value according to an overlay of a different colour and its opacity setting?

Comment: @Pekka Opacity doesn't really have anything to do with it; he wants to convert a float in the range 0-1 to the appropriate 1-byte hex value, so 1.0 goes to 0xFF

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the most basic level, you're just converting a decimal to hex: [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript):

```
yourNum = yourNum.toString(16);
```

The 0.0 - 1.0 range is just a percentage format of the 0-255 range. So multiply your value (e.g. 0.5 * 255) then convert to hex, you'll get the correct value.

Comment: The original version (pre-multiple ninja edits) was incorrect, just pointed to the SO post and had no mention of multiplying by 255

Comment: I have no Idea why you voted down, I saw some people are very strict to put answer then a reference not a reference only, but a vote down is very exaggerated specially you posted a good answer.

Comment: [The number one reason to downvote an answer is that it is wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers), which it was.  I've since removed the downvote as it has been corrected.

Comment: Guess I would have found that question if I didn't have opacity stuck in my head.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the suggestions of the other answers:

```
Math.floor(0.0 * 255).toString(16);   // Returns '00'
Math.floor(0.5 * 255).toString(16);   // Returns '75'
Math.floor(1.0 * 255).toString(16);   // Returns 'FF'
```

Comment: Why floor instead of round?

Answer (score 3):

```js
function applyOpacity(color, opacity) {
  if (typeof color !== 'string' || color.length !== 7) return color;

  if (opacity < 0) opacity = 0;
  else if (opacity > 100) opacity = 100;

  opacity = Math.round(opacity * 2.55);

  return color + opacity.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, '0');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Multiply by 255  (this assumes your input range is from 0 to 1 only, and this scales it up to 0-255)
2. `Math.floor()`
3. [Convert that decimal number to the hex equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple function to play hex colour code opacity.

```js
const colour (colour, value) => {
  const opacity = Math.floor(0.1 * value * 255).toString(16);
  return colour + opacity;
};

colour (#172B4D, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an util function like

```
const convertTotHex = (num) => {
    const hex = Math.round(((num/100)*255)).toString(16);
    return hex.length > 1 ? hex : 0+hex;
}
```