# How do I base64 encode data (not a string) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, encoding, base64

I'm porting functionality from an Objective-C iPhone app to a Javascript iPhone app (Appcelerator Titanium). In Objective-C I have an NSData object that represents this token:

```
//NSData object printed to the console:
<0cd9f571 b0e66e6d ca410d12 f67a404a 7e64b9b5 d2483fd9 63a9267b 1c7609e2>
```

It's not a string, it's an NSData object -- an object-oriented wrapper for a byte buffer. When I base64 encode the object, I get this result:

```
//base64 encoded NSData object
DNn1cbDmbm3KQQ0S9npASn5kubXSSD/ZY6kmexx2CeI=
```

In my javascript implementation, I have a string representation of the same token. It looks like this:

```
//string version of the token in my javascript implementation
0cd9f571b0e66e6dca410d12f67a404a7e64b9b5d2483fd963a9267b1c7609e2
```

When I base64 encode the string object in javascript, I get this result:

```
//base64 encoded token (string) in javascript
MGNkOWY1NzFiMGU2NmU2ZGNhNDEwZDEyZjY3YTQwNGE3ZTY0YjliNWQyNDgzZmQ5NjNhOTI2N2IxYzc2MDllMg==
```

The problem is, the web service I'm posting to doesn't want the base64 encoded string, it wants the base64 encoded data! How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: isn't the 0cd9f571b0e66e6dca410d12f67a404a7e64b9b5d2483fd963a9267b1c7609e2 base64 encoded already ? from the looks of it I think it is

Comment: @TheBrain: it's a hexadecimal number. In other words, it's base 16 encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the hexadecimal string before base64 encoding it should fix the issue. To do this in JS:

```
if (! Array.prototype.map) {
    Array.prototype.map = function(f) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i=0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            result[i] = f(this[i], i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
String.prototype.b16decode = function() {
    return this.match(/../g).map(
        function (x) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(x, 16));
        }
    ).join('');
}
```

For example, running

```
btoa('0cd9f571b0e66e6dca410d12f67a404a7e64b9b5d2483fd963a9267b1c7609e2'.b16decode())
```

(where [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa) is a base64 encoding function some browsers supply) results in

```
"DNn1cbDmbm3KQQ0S9npASn5kubXSSD/ZY6kmexx2CeI="
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the original hex string as list of integers. See [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Then you need to modify one of the many base64 js algorithms to use the integers instead of *charCodeAt*. See http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html
Also see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/base64encoder.aspx which is a direct integer to base64 algo (most are byte or string to base64).

Even though that last example C# you should be able to convert it to JS.

If I have the time later on I will see if I can write the code.

Comment: Modifying a base64 encoder isn't necessary. One could use `parseInt(_, 16)` to convert the hexadecimal string to a string containing binary data, then pass that to a base64 encoder. With a suitable `Array.prototype.map`, a simple `hexstr.match(/../g).map(function (x) {return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(x, 16))}).join('')` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

search for toDataUrl() function