# how do convert hexadecimal into ip javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a hexadecimal into equivalent IP in javascript?
My hexadecial value is
      `0A.0A.0A.0A`
and i have to convert this into ip?
     `10.10.10.10`

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

```
var hex = "0A.0A.0A.0A";
var splitData = hex.split(".");
for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++){
    splitData[i] = parseInt(splitData[i], 16);
}

var ip = splitData.join(".");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
'0A.0A.0A.0A'.replace( /(\w{2})/gi, function( str, match ) {
    return parseInt( match, 16 );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to do most of the work:

```
addr  = '0A.0A.0A.0A';

// Break it into hex pieces.
parts = addr.split('.');

// Convert each piece to decimal using parseInt's radix argument.
for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i)
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i], 16);

// And put it back together using join and implicit conversion
// of numbers to strings.
addr = parts.join('.');
// addr is now "10.10.10.10"
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

```
function ConvertHexIPToBase10(ip) {
    var vals = ip.split(".");
    var op = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        op.push(parseInt(vals[i], 16));
    }
    return op.join(".");
}

var hexIP = "0A.0A.0A.0A";
var newIP = ConvertHexIPToBase10(hexIP);
```