# How do I implement hex2bin()?

Tags: javascript, binary-data, hex

I need to communicate between Javascript and PHP (I use jQuery for AJAX), but the output of the PHP script may contain binary data. That's why I use `bin2hex()` and `json_encode()` on PHP side.

How do I convert the hexadecimal string in binary string, with JavaScript?

Comment: @MartyIX: Here is a [BSD-licensed Javascript function](http://freebeer.smithii.com/www/_source.php?file=%2Fhome%2Fross%2Fpublic_html%2Ffreebeer%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fbin2hex.js) that does what you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have support for binary data. Nevertheless you can emulate this with regular strings.

```
var hex = "375771", // ASCII HEX: 37="7", 57="W", 71="q"
    bytes = [],
    str;

for(var i=0; i< hex.length-1; i+=2){
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
}

str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes);

alert(str); // 7Wq
```

Comment: when this answer was written, it was probably correct, but JS does support binary data now, with the [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) :)  it's very cubersome to use compared to php's binary strings which essentially are Uint8Array's already, but it's better than nothing ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 61):

To answer your question:

```
function Hex2Bin(n){if(!checkHex(n))return 0;return parseInt(n,16).toString(2)}
```

Here are some further functions you may find useful for working with binary data:

```
//Useful Functions
function checkBin(n){return/^[01]{1,64}$/.test(n)}
function checkDec(n){return/^[0-9]{1,64}$/.test(n)}
function checkHex(n){return/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,64}$/.test(n)}
function pad(s,z){s=""+s;return s.length<z?pad("0"+s,z):s}
function unpad(s){s=""+s;return s.replace(/^0+/,'')}

//Decimal operations
function Dec2Bin(n){if(!checkDec(n)||n<0)return 0;return n.toString(2)}
function Dec2Hex(n){if(!checkDec(n)||n<0)return 0;return n.toString(16)}

//Binary Operations
function Bin2Dec(n){if(!checkBin(n))return 0;return parseInt(n,2).toString(10)}
function Bin2Hex(n){if(!checkBin(n))return 0;return parseInt(n,2).toString(16)}

//Hexadecimal Operations
function Hex2Bin(n){if(!checkHex(n))return 0;return parseInt(n,16).toString(2)}
function Hex2Dec(n){if(!checkHex(n))return 0;return parseInt(n,16).toString(10)}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with actual binary data, rather with ASCII representations of binary data.

Comment: Your functions are wrong. At least `Hex2Bin` and `Bin2Hex`. Didn't even try other afterI got wrong results with those two. Try yourself `Hex2Bin` => `Bin2Hex`

Comment: I've been using this set for a long time. And I am beginning to use Hex2Bin and realized it just now. Hex2Bin is broken. I think Bin2Hex is also wrong.

Comment: For the two functions, here is one that works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204912/javascript-need-functions-to-convert-a-string-containing-binary-to-hex-then-co

Comment: It depends if you mean 1 bit binary representation (0/1) or 8 bit binary representation (bytes of data).  In this answer "bin" means base 2 (binary 1s and 0s)

Comment: Your Hex2Bin function doesn't work for anything longer than a single pair of hex values.

Answer (score 10):

```
function hex2bin(hex)
{
    var bytes = [], str;

    for(var i=0; i< hex.length-1; i+=2)
        bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));

    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes);    
}
```

thanks to [Andris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695514/669677)!

---

Other useful information about this topic (dex2bin,bin2dec) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript).
According to that, here is a `bin2hex` solution:

```
parseInt(1100,2).toString(16); //--> c
```

Answer (score 5):

Although not an answer to the actual question, it is perhaps useful in this case to also know how to reverse the process:

```
function bin2hex (bin)
{

  var i = 0, l = bin.length, chr, hex = ''

  for (i; i < l; ++i)
  {

    chr = bin.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)

    hex += chr.length < 2 ? '0' + chr : chr

  }

  return hex

}
```

As an example, using `hex2bin` on `b637eb9146e84cb79f6d981ac9463de1` returns `¶7ëFèL·mÉF=á`, and then passing this to `bin2hex` returns `b637eb9146e84cb79f6d981ac9463de1`.

It might also be useful to prototype these functions to the `String` object:

```
String.prototype.hex2bin = function ()
{

  var i = 0, l = this.length - 1, bytes = []

  for (i; i < l; i += 2)
  {
    bytes.push(parseInt(this.substr(i, 2), 16))
  }

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes)   

}

String.prototype.bin2hex = function ()
{

  var i = 0, l = this.length, chr, hex = ''

  for (i; i < l; ++i)
  {

    chr = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)

    hex += chr.length < 2 ? '0' + chr : chr

  }

  return hex

}

alert('b637eb9146e84cb79f6d981ac9463de1'.hex2bin().bin2hex())
```

Comment: bin2hex seems really inefficient (and slow) if I want to, say, convert a large image file into a hex string...

Answer (score 3):

All proposed solutions use `String.fromCharCode`, why not simply using `unescape`?

```
String.prototype.hex2bin = function()
{ 
   var i = 0, len = this.length, result = "";

   //Converting the hex string into an escaped string, so if the hex string is "a2b320", it will become "%a2%b3%20"
   for(; i < len; i+=2)
      result += '%' + this.substr(i, 2);      

   return unescape(result);
}
```

and then:

```
alert( "68656c6c6f".hex2bin() ); //shows "hello"
```

Comment: *why not simply using unescape* - Just because it's deprecated. ;)

Comment: you can use decodeURIComponent instead of unescape and this is perfectly fine. However thanks @Marco, I used your solution

Answer (score 3):

With reference to node.js  ( not in browser ).

Basically it's all over-engineered and does not work well.

responses are out of alignment and though text-wise they are the same bit wise everything is all over the place :

```
curl http://phpimpl.domain.com/testhex.php | xxd

00000000: de56 a735 4739 c01d f2dc e14b ba30 8af0  .Q.%G9.....;.0..

curl http://nodejs.domain.com/ | xxd

00000000: c39e 56c2 a725 4739 c380 c3ad c3b1 c39c  ..Q..%G9........
00000010: c3a1 37c2 6b30 c28f c3b0                 ..;..0....
```

The proper way to implement this in node is :

```
function hex2bin(hex){
   return new Buffer(hex,"hex");
}


curl http://nodejs.domain.com/ | xxd

00000000: de56 a735 4739 c01d f2dc e14b ba30 8af0  .Q.%G9.....;.0..
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of hex2bin in JS that takes a string and returns Uint8Array, works both in browsers and nodejs,

```
function hex2bin(hex) {
  var length = hex.length / 2;
  var result = new Uint8Array(length);
  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    result[i] = parseInt(hex.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
  }
  return result;
}
```

And its inverse,

```
function bin2hex(bin) {
  return Array.from(bin).map(function (x) {
    return x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  }).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.hex2bin = function () {
    if (this.length % 2 !== 0) return false;

    let bytes = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i += 2) {
        let charCode = parseInt(this.substring(i, i + 2), 16)
        bytes.push(charCode)
    }

    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes)
        .replace(/\x00+$/g, '') // not necessary
        .trim()
}
    
console.log('78534F4C41527800000000000000000000000000'.hex2bin()) // xSOLARx (length: 7)
console.log('4D554C5449504153530000000000000000000000'.hex2bin()) // MULTIPASS (length: 9)
console.log('4C5A415200000000000000000000000000000000'.hex2bin()) // LZAR (length: 4)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript does actually contain support for binary data. See [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint8Array).

Just read each byte from the array and convert it into hexadecimal.

Answer (score -1):

If someone needs the other direction (bin to hex), here is it:

```
function bin2hex(bin) {
    return new Buffer(bin).toString("hex");
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined