# JavaScript double backslash in WebSocket messages

Tags: javascript, python, struct, byte

I'm sending binary data over WebSocket to a Python application. This binary data is decoded by calling `struct.unpack("BH", data")` on it, requiring a 4-long bytes object.
The problem I'm currently facing is, that all data contains duplicate backslashes, even in `arraybuffer` mode and is therefor 16 bytes long. I can't detect the varying size because there is data appended to the back of it (irrelevant for this question) and even if I could, I also couldn't find a way to strip the backslashes in Python.

How the data is sent:

```js
// this.webSocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";   
var message = "\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00"; // escaping required
var buffer = new Int8Array(message.length);
for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    buffer[i] = message.charCodeAt(i);
}
this.webSocket.send(buffer.buffer);
```

In comparison, this is how said data looks when defined in Python:

```py
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00'
```

And this is how it looks as a received message:

```
b'\\x05\\x00\\x00\\x00'
```

The ideal solution for this issue would be on the JavaScript-side because I can't really change the implementation of the Python application without breaking Python-based clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the message as bytes and not as string:

```
var buffer = new Int8Array([5,0,0,0])
this.webSocket.send(buffer.buffer)
```

Comment: Is `5` equivalent to `"\\x05"`?

Comment: No, "\\x05" are 4 bytes, but 5 is equal to the byte `\x05`.

Comment: What do you mean with «format»? This is a string with a backslash, `x` `0` and `5`.

Comment: Why are `"\\"` included in original string? Is `"\\x05"` intended to be the literal string `x05`? Why are `\\`, `x`, `0` not included at first element of `Uint8Array`? For example using approach described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204912/javascript-need-functions-to-convert-a-string-containing-binary-to-hex-then-co, `+parseInt("0x05", 16).toString(2)` returns `101`, `String.fromCodePoint(101)` returns `"e"`. Is this not incorrect conversion?  Can ask a Question if that would be more appropriate.

Comment: "format" as in is  `"\\x05"` intended to be a literal string? Or is `"\\x05"` "binary"?

Comment: the decimal number 5 as a number  to the base of 2 is 101. That is not the decimal number 101.

Comment: Been too long since last time looked into boolean algrebra