# Node.js/JS implementations of PHP's `hex2bin` returns wrong results. How to get the same result?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

This is a PHP code:

```
$h = hex2bin('db6dc3f86800da4f7c19e643e8941ebb');
$md5 = md5($h);
echo $md5; // ==> b885730327999e8823d113161c3538d3
```

And this is the same in Node.js. But the result is different:

```
let h = hex2bin('db6dc3f86800da4f7c19e643e8941ebb');
let md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(h).digest('hex');
console.log(md5); ==> // a141519bf4b0acf2221ed94e721ddc7d
```

I have used four different variants of JS analogs of `hex2bin` that I could find in the internet. All of them do not return the same as PHP does. But more than that, none of these JS functions return the same result as others JS functions.

1. From here http://locutus.io/php/strings/hex2bin/
2. From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987042/1114926
3. From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41550641/1114926
4. From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17224848/1114926

Why is it so? Is it really impossible to have PHP's `hex2bin` in JS/Node.js? Do I need to set up whole PHP interpreter just for this one function?

Comment: It looks like at least one of those functions is converting hex to binary numbers (01001100 etc), where hex2bin() is converting hex to a binary string (binary data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after some time digging in the web I found the correct solution for you. I think the problem was in javascript's `md5` implementation because most of the `hex2bin` javascript functions that I found on the web were returning always the same results.

This **MD5** javascript implementation I found **[here](http://lig-membres.imag.fr/donsez/cours/exemplescourstechnoweb/js_securehash/md5src.html)**. As you can see the `hex2bin` implementation is quite short and you can find it on a lot of places.

```js
/*

    MD5 IMPLEMENTATION

*/

var hex_chr = "0123456789abcdef";

function rhex(num) {
  str = "";
  for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
    str += hex_chr.charAt((num >> (j * 8 + 4)) & 0x0F) +
    hex_chr.charAt((num >> (j * 8)) & 0x0F);
  return str;
}

/*
 * Convert a string to a sequence of 16-word blocks, stored as an array.
 * Append padding bits and the length, as described in the MD5 standard.
 */
function str2blks_MD5(str) {
  nblk = ((str.length + 8) >> 6) + 1;
  blks = new Array(nblk * 16);
  for (i = 0; i < nblk * 16; i++) blks[i] = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    blks[i >> 2] |= str.charCodeAt(i) << ((i % 4) * 8);
  blks[i >> 2] |= 0x80 << ((i % 4) * 8);
  blks[nblk * 16 - 2] = str.length * 8;
  return blks;
}

/*
 * Add integers, wrapping at 2^32. This uses 16-bit operations internally 
 * to work around bugs in some JS interpreters.
 */
function add(x, y) {
  var lsw = (x & 0xFFFF) + (y & 0xFFFF);
  var msw = (x >> 16) + (y >> 16) + (lsw >> 16);
  return (msw << 16) | (lsw & 0xFFFF);
}

/*
 * Bitwise rotate a 32-bit number to the left
 */
function rol(num, cnt) {
  return (num << cnt) | (num >>> (32 - cnt));
}

/*
 * These functions implement the basic operation for each round of the
 * algorithm.
 */
function cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t) {
  return add(rol(add(add(a, q), add(x, t)), s), b);
}

function ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
  return cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
  return cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
  return cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}

function ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
  return cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

/*
 * Take a string and return the hex representation of its MD5.
 */
function calcMD5(str) {
  x = str2blks_MD5(str);
  a = 1732584193;
  b = -271733879;
  c = -1732584194;
  d = 271733878;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i += 16) {
    olda = a;
    oldb = b;
    oldc = c;
    oldd = d;

    a = ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 0], 7, -680876936);
    d = ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 1], 12, -389564586);
    c = ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 2], 17, 606105819);
    b = ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 3], 22, -1044525330);
    a = ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 4], 7, -176418897);
    d = ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 5], 12, 1200080426);
    c = ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 6], 17, -1473231341);
    b = ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 7], 22, -45705983);
    a = ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 8], 7, 1770035416);
    d = ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 9], 12, -1958414417);
    c = ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 10], 17, -42063);
    b = ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 11], 22, -1990404162);
    a = ff(a, b, c, d, x[i + 12], 7, 1804603682);
    d = ff(d, a, b, c, x[i + 13], 12, -40341101);
    c = ff(c, d, a, b, x[i + 14], 17, -1502002290);
    b = ff(b, c, d, a, x[i + 15], 22, 1236535329);

    a = gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 1], 5, -165796510);
    d = gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 6], 9, -1069501632);
    c = gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 11], 14, 643717713);
    b = gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 0], 20, -373897302);
    a = gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 5], 5, -701558691);
    d = gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 10], 9, 38016083);
    c = gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 15], 14, -660478335);
    b = gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 4], 20, -405537848);
    a = gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 9], 5, 568446438);
    d = gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 14], 9, -1019803690);
    c = gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 3], 14, -187363961);
    b = gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 8], 20, 1163531501);
    a = gg(a, b, c, d, x[i + 13], 5, -1444681467);
    d = gg(d, a, b, c, x[i + 2], 9, -51403784);
    c = gg(c, d, a, b, x[i + 7], 14, 1735328473);
    b = gg(b, c, d, a, x[i + 12], 20, -1926607734);

    a = hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 5], 4, -378558);
    d = hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 8], 11, -2022574463);
    c = hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 11], 16, 1839030562);
    b = hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 14], 23, -35309556);
    a = hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 1], 4, -1530992060);
    d = hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 4], 11, 1272893353);
    c = hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 7], 16, -155497632);
    b = hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 10], 23, -1094730640);
    a = hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 13], 4, 681279174);
    d = hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 0], 11, -358537222);
    c = hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 3], 16, -722521979);
    b = hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 6], 23, 76029189);
    a = hh(a, b, c, d, x[i + 9], 4, -640364487);
    d = hh(d, a, b, c, x[i + 12], 11, -421815835);
    c = hh(c, d, a, b, x[i + 15], 16, 530742520);
    b = hh(b, c, d, a, x[i + 2], 23, -995338651);

    a = ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 0], 6, -198630844);
    d = ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 7], 10, 1126891415);
    c = ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 14], 15, -1416354905);
    b = ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 5], 21, -57434055);
    a = ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 12], 6, 1700485571);
    d = ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 3], 10, -1894986606);
    c = ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 10], 15, -1051523);
    b = ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 1], 21, -2054922799);
    a = ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 8], 6, 1873313359);
    d = ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 15], 10, -30611744);
    c = ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 6], 15, -1560198380);
    b = ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 13], 21, 1309151649);
    a = ii(a, b, c, d, x[i + 4], 6, -145523070);
    d = ii(d, a, b, c, x[i + 11], 10, -1120210379);
    c = ii(c, d, a, b, x[i + 2], 15, 718787259);
    b = ii(b, c, d, a, x[i + 9], 21, -343485551);

    a = add(a, olda);
    b = add(b, oldb);
    c = add(c, oldc);
    d = add(d, oldd);
  }
  return rhex(a) + rhex(b) + rhex(c) + rhex(d);
}


/*

    HEX2BIN IMPLEMENTATION

*/
function hex2bin(hex) {
  var bytes = [],
    str;

  for (var i = 0; i < hex.length - 1; i += 2)
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes);
}
var inputStr = 'db6dc3f86800da4f7c19e643e8941ebb';
var hex2bin = hex2bin(inputStr);
console.log('initial = ' + inputStr);
console.log('hex2bin = ' + hex2bin);
console.log('md5 = ' + calcMD5(hex2bin));
```