# Javascript - turning on bits

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-manipulation, buffer

I have some understanding about bits and bytes, shifting concept and so - but no actual experience with it.

So:
I need to turn an array of true and false into a buffer, made of 1344 bits (which i send using UDP packets).

The other side will evaluate the buffer bit by bit..

Since i'm new to nodeJs, feel free to add tips or point me to new directions.

```
var arrBinary = new Array(1344);
for(i=0;i<1344;i++)arrBinary[i]=0;    
// some code here, which will turn some of the array's elements to 1

var arrForBuffer = new Array(168);
for(i=0;i<168;i++)arrForBuffer[i]=0;

var x = buffer.from(arr);

/****** the question ******/
// How to change and set arrForBuffer so it will represent the arrBinary Bits state?
```

Comment: Sounds like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204912/javascript-need-functions-to-convert-a-string-containing-binary-to-hex-then-co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript supports bits operations like in every major language. You can use the `|` and `<<` operators to achieve this transformation:

```js
const size = 16;
const packsize = 8;

const arrBinary = new Array(size).fill(false);
arrBinary[2] = true;
arrBinary[6] = true;
arrBinary[8] = true;

let arrForBuffer = new Array(size / packsize);

let acc = 0;
let byteCounter = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arrBinary.length; i++) {
  if (arrBinary[i]) {
    acc |= 1 << (i % packsize);
  }

  if (i % packsize == packsize - 1) {
    arrForBuffer[byteCounter] = acc;
    byteCounter++;
    acc = 0;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < arrForBuffer.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${i}: ${arrForBuffer[i]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some bitshifting as you said:

```
// arrForBuffer must be initialized with 0s

for(let i = 0; i < 1344; i++) 
 arrForBuffer[ Math.floor(i / 8) ] += arrBinary[i] << (7 - (i % 8));
```

The first bit for example of `arrBinary` will be left shifted by 7 and added to the first byte, the second will be shifted left by 6, and so on. The 8th will be shifted left by 7 again, and will be added to the second byte.

It might be more readable (and possibly more performant), if it would be written as:

```
 for(let byte = 0; byte < 168; byte++) {
   arrForBuffer[byte] = 
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 0] << 7 |
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 1] << 6 |
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 2] << 5 |
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 3] << 4 |
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 4] << 3 |
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 5] << 2 |
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 6] << 1 |
     arrBinary[byte * 8 + 7];
 }
```

Comment: 1. thanks 2. i understand the concept, never used it and don't know the operators and how they work.
can  you please add some explanation to it?