# String of Binary to Buffer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, buffer

I'm trying to convert a string of `0` and `1` into the equivalent `Buffer` by parsing the character stream as a UTF-16 encoding.

For example:

```js
var binary = "01010101010101000100010"
```

The result of that would be the following Buffer

```
<Buffer 55 54>
```

Please note `Buffer.from(string, "binary")` is not valid as it creates a buffer where each individual `0` or `1` is parsed as it's own Latin One-Byte encoded string. From the Node.js documentation:

> 'latin1': A way of encoding the Buffer into a one-byte encoded string (as defined by the IANA in RFC 1345, page 63, to be the Latin-1 supplement block and C0/C1 control codes).
>
> 'binary': Alias for 'latin1'.

Comment: You could generate a HEX string from that ([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204912/javascript-need-functions-to-convert-a-string-containing-binary-to-hex-then-co)) and use `Buffer.from(hexStr, "hex")`. By the way, your example is wrong, `0101010101010100` is `5554`, you have 7 extra bits in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use "".match to find all the groups of 16 bits.
- Convert the binary string to number using parseInt
- Create an Uint16Array and convert it to a Buffer

Tested on node 10.x

```
function binaryStringToBuffer(string) {
    const groups = string.match(/[01]{16}/g);
    const numbers = groups.map(binary => parseInt(binary, 2))

    return Buffer.from(new Uint16Array(numbers).buffer);
}

console.log(binaryStringToBuffer("01010101010101000100010"))
```