# convert hex to binary in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert hex into binary using javascript.

example:
21 23 00 6A D0 0F 69 4C E1 20

should result in:
‭0010000100100011000000000110101011010000000011110110100101001100‬

Does anyone know of a javascript library I might use to accomplish this?

Harriet

Comment: We do not recommend libraries here! If you're interested in an algorithm to do that, you may be in the right place. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695450/how-to-program-hex2bin-in-javascript

Comment: Are you sure about your binary result ?

Comment: @Seblor, I actually input the hex string into my desktop calculator and hit binary for the above conversion.

Comment: @Harriet you are missing 16 digits at the end (right side)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can create a function converting a hex number to binary with something like this :

```
function hex2bin(hex){
    return ("00000000" + (parseInt(hex, 16)).toString(2)).substr(-8);
}
```

For formatting you just fill a string with 8 `0`, and you concatenate your number. Then, for converting, what you do is basicaly getting a string or number, use the `parseInt` function with the input number value and its base (base 16 for hex here), then you print it to base 2 with the `toString` function.
And finally, you extract the last 8 characters to get your formatted string.

---

## 2018 Edit :

As this answer is still being read, I wanted to provide another syntax for the function's body, using the ES8 (ECMAScript 2017) [`String.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method :

```
function hex2bin(hex){
    return (parseInt(hex, 16).toString(2)).padStart(8, '0');
}
```

Using `padStart` will fill the string until its lengths matches the first parameter, and the second parameter is the filler character (blank space by default).

*End of edit*

---

To use this on a full string like yours, use a simple `forEach` :

```
var result = ""
"21 23 00 6A D0 0F 69 4C E1 20".split(" ").forEach(str => {
  result += hex2bin(str)
})
console.log(result)
```

The output will be :

> 00100001001000110000000001101010110100000000111101101001010011001110000100100000

Comment: Why first approach does not work for this hex: `F9C6400001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000000000000000000`?

Comment: @OPV That is because the first version uses a substring function, limiting the output to 8 digits, since I did not expect the input to be more than a byte, and wanted to output exactly one byte, including the leading 0s. The second version, using `padStart`, outputs *at least* one "full" byte.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, previous answers seem not to be working with very large values (e.g., 512 bits so common in cryptography). This solution may be a bit slower, but it guarantees dealing with input of any length.

```
function hex2bin(hex){
    hex = hex.replace("0x", "").toLowerCase();
    var out = "";
    for(var c of hex) {
        switch(c) {
            case '0': out += "0000"; break;
            case '1': out += "0001"; break;
            case '2': out += "0010"; break;
            case '3': out += "0011"; break;
            case '4': out += "0100"; break;
            case '5': out += "0101"; break;
            case '6': out += "0110"; break;
            case '7': out += "0111"; break;
            case '8': out += "1000"; break;
            case '9': out += "1001"; break;
            case 'a': out += "1010"; break;
            case 'b': out += "1011"; break;
            case 'c': out += "1100"; break;
            case 'd': out += "1101"; break;
            case 'e': out += "1110"; break;
            case 'f': out += "1111"; break;
            default: return "";
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Probably the best response, thank You!

Answer (score 10):

You can use `parseInt` and `toString` to change the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) of a number.

```js
function convertNumber(n, fromBase, toBase) {
  if (fromBase === void 0) {
    fromBase = 10;
  }
  if (toBase === void 0) {
    toBase = 10;
  }
  return parseInt(n.toString(), fromBase).toString(toBase);
}
console.log(
  convertNumber("f", 16, 10),
  convertNumber("f", 16, 2),
  convertNumber("1111", 2, 10),
  convertNumber("1111", 2, 16)
);
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest implementation

```
const hex2bin = (data) => data.split('').map(i => 
parseInt(i, 16).toString(2).padStart(4, '0')).join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me.

```
function hex2bin(hexSource) {
    var bin = '';
    for (var i=0;i<hexSource.length;i=i+2) {
        bin += String.fromCharCode(hexdec(hexSource.substr(i,2)));
    }
    return bin;
}

function hexdec(hexString) {
    hexString = (hexString + '').replace(/[^a-f0-9]/gi, '')
    return parseInt(hexString, 16)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be faster method, concept is considering integer's capacity we can divide hex string into blocks of 8 chars instead of 1 char:

```
function hexToBinary(hex) {
    var binary = "";
    var remainingSize = hex.length;
    for (var p = 0; p < hex.length/8; p++) {
        //In case remaining hex length (or initial) is not multiple of 8
        var blockSize = remainingSize < 8 ? remainingSize  : 8;

        binary += parseInt(hex.substr(p * 8, blockSize), 16).toString(2).padStart(blockSize*4,"0");

        remainingSize -= blockSize;
    }
    return binary;
}
```

Comment: It's faster compared to other parseInt/toString/padStart methods. But it's slower than using a lookup table for each character (which you could then speed up further with a 2-char lookup table, 3-char lookup table, etc.) For very large hex strings, you could generate the lookup table as a one-time cost. At some point there are diminishing returns on a larger lookup table. Fun stuff to play with.

Answer (score 0):

I agree for hex to binary going character by character isn't the fastest or most efficient, but I think it's difficult to do that and still have readable code. I think these two are good starting points for those less familiar.

```
function hex2bin(hex) {
  let bin = "";
  let bitsInHex = 4;

  Array.from(hex).forEach(
    function (char) {
      let currentBin = parseInt(char, 16).toString(2);

      if (currentBin.length < bitsInHex) {
        let padding = "0".repeat(bitsInHex-currentBin.length);
        currentBin = padding + currentBin;
      }

      bin += currentBin;
    }
  );

  return bin;
}

function bin2hex(bin) {
  let hex = "";
  let bitsInHex = 4;

  for (let i = 0; i < bin.length; i = i + bitsInHex) {
    let eightBits = bin.substr(i, bitsInHex);
    let currentHex = (parseInt(eightBits, 2)).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    hex += currentHex;
  }

  return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Javascript gives only `0000` if the character length is greater than **12**. I am self-taught JS, so don't know the reason.

But I have a workaround for this problem. Just divided the original string into an array of smaller chunks, and then find their binary value.

```js
function hex2bin(hex) {
    let chunks = hex.match(/.{1,8}/g), bin = ''
    chunks.forEach(c => (bin += parseInt(c, 16).toString(2)))
    bin = bin.padStart(4, '0')
    return bin
}
```

I think this would be much easier to implement than to use individual binary values of hex as mentioned in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053624/convert-hex-to-binary-in-javascript#64235212).
My solution is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053624/convert-hex-to-binary-in-javascript#67454787)

Answer (score 0):

I found a library what does this easier.

```
https://gist.github.com/faisalman/4213592
```

to convert hex to binary type ConvertBase.hex2bin('your hex number');

Comment: There are already lots of vanilla JS examples up for grabs in this old question. Maybe there is no need to point to a third party library.