# Function for converting hex and decimal

Tags: javascript

**What would the function be for when the user inputs, it converts the input to both hex and binary?**

The algorithm for converting from decimal to binary is this:

- Take your decimal number and determine the remainder if you divide that number by two. The remainder is now the bit in your ONES (2^0) place. Hint: the modulo operator % will give you the REMAINDER of a division. For example, 5%2 is 1 because the remainder of dividing 5 by 2 is 1. 4%2 is 0, because there is no remainder.
- Now, we're going to update your decimal number: divide the decimal number and round down to get your NEW decimal number

```
var hexLetters = "0123456789ABCDEF".split("");


var decimalNum = Number(window.prompt("Enter a decimal number to convert"));


var binaryNum= "";
*  binary conversion *


console.log("The number " + decimalNum + " in binary is: ")
console.log(binaryNum);


var hexNum = "";
*binary conversion*

/************************************* */

console.log("The number " + decimalNum + " in hexadecimal is: ")
console.log(hexNum);
```

**What would the function be for when the user inputs, it converts the input to both hex and binary**

Comment: Please include your best attempt to solve this and tell us what problems you are having.

Comment: Why not just call `parseInt(value, base)` and transform it into decimal from any base?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to convert a hex number to binary:

```
function hexToBin(hex){
return ("00000000" + (parseInt(hex, 16)).toString(2)).substr(-8);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To play in **safe** the user must choose the target from (Hex, Binary, decimal)  to (Hex, Binary, decimal) to know the right function to use

```
 // 1. Convert to Binary

    function convertToBinary(number) {
        let bin = 0;
        let rem, i = 1, step = 1;
        while (number != 0) {
            rem = number % 2;
            console.log(
                `Step ${step++}: ${number}/2, Remainder = ${rem}, Quotient = ${parseInt(number/2)}`
            );
            number = parseInt(number / 2);
            bin = bin + rem * i;
            i = i * 10;
        }
        console.log(`Binary: ${bin}`);
    }
    
    convertToBinary(2);

    
    // 2. Convert to Hex 

    function hex2bin(hex){
        return (parseInt(hex, 16).toString(2)).padStart(8, '0');
    }
    function convertHexToBinary(hex) {
      var result = "";
    hex.split(" ").forEach(sting => {
      result += hex2bin(sting)
    })
    console.log(result)
    }
    
    convertHexToBinary('2AB');
```

Hex answer credit for https://stackoverflow.com/a/45054052/14292804

Binary answer credit for [https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/decimal-binary#:~:text=The%20parseInt()%20method%20is,decimal%20number%20to%20binary%20number](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/decimal-binary#:%7E:text=The%20parseInt()%20method%20is,decimal%20number%20to%20binary%20number).

Comment: Does not seem to be working, the binary and hexcode are the same each time.

Comment: it's working my friend I test it in 10 cases, maybe you made something