# Equivalent of python's int('hex-string', 16) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Is there an equivalent of python's int('hex-string', 16) function in Javascript?

Comment: `yourNumber = parseInt(hexString, 16);`

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var result = parseInt("0x42", 16);  // 66
```

Comment: If you place `0x` you may omit radix: `parseInt("0x42")`