# porting long hex encoding from java to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, encoding, hex

I want to encode a javascript number-type or string in the same way I encode a Java long.

java

```
long toEncode = 1397378335821717182L;

String encoded = Long.toHexString(toEncode); //"13647c315b7adebe"
```

javascript

```
var toEncode = '1397378335821717182';

var encoded = //missing code, should be'13647c315b7adebe' in the end as well
```

doing https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805/1052539 I get '13647c315b7adf00'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Comment: @Quentin not a duplicate, his numbers don't fit in a double so doing it that way he'll lose precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For node.js [bigdecimal.js](https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js) works pretty well.

```
BigDec> (new bigdecimal.BigInteger('1397378335821717182')).toString(16)
'13647c315b7adebe'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need a javascript bignum library.

<strike>This one seems to do what you want:
http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/</strike>

edit: The one I linked doesn't seem to work. Look around a bit for a nice one (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library), but using [another google hit](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html), some simple example code is:

```
<script>
  var toEncode = str2bigInt('1397378335821717182', 10);
  document.write(bigInt2str(toEncode, 16).toLowerCase());
</script>

returns: 13647c315b7adebe
```

Or with [this library](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) (which is, at the very least, better scoped):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="biginteger.js"></script>
<script>
  var toEncode = BigInteger.parse('1397378335821717182');
  document.write(toEncode.toString(16).toLowerCase());
</script>

returns: 13647c315b7adebe
```

Comment: @forste There. I'd recommend the second one.

Comment: ty again for updating! however, I should have made it more obvious that I need this for node.js. I have put an own answer for this

Comment: @forste oh yeah didn't see that tag. At least we've got answers for both then. :-)