# How to convert color from (rrr ggg bbb) to RRGGBB by javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide

I have this code (in Selenium IDE): 
`storeEval | window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]).getPropertyValue('background-color') | result`

it's returns me color in `(rrr, ggg, bbb)`, how can i get this color in `RRGGBB`?

Comment: Here is how to do the conversion in Javascript http://stackoverflow.com/q/57803/1399920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
command: storeEval
target : color = window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]).getPropertyValue('background-color'); colorArr = color.replace(/[(rgb()\)]/g, '').split(','); hexString = parseInt(colorArr[0]).toString(16) + parseInt(colorArr[1]).toString(16) + parseInt(colorArr[2]).toString(16);
value  : result
```

Comment: "[info] echo: NaNe6ff;" must be #CCE6FF ))

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь ) чуть чуть неправильный replace и он не мог конвертировать [0] массив. ещё раз спасибо

Comment: @user1211063 you are welcome. I missed, that it returns rgb(rrr, ggg, bbb). Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the decimal value (0 - 255) to hex (0 - FF)

```
var hexString = redNumber.toString(16) + greenNumber.toString(16) + blueNumber.toString(16);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can not undestand, how can I use this with my code in Selenium IDE (