# How to represent number as hexadecimal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a DEC number to HEX using JavaScript.

The number I am trying to convert is 28.

I have tried using:

```
function h2d(h) {return parseInt(h,16);}
```

however it returns 40

I have also tried using:

```
function d2h(d) {return d.toString(16);}
```

however it returns 28

The final result should return 1C but I can't seem to work it out.

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like you're having trouble because your input is a String when you're looking for a number. Try changing your d2h() code to look like this and you should be set:

```
function d2h(d) { return (+d).toString(16); }
```

The plus sign (`+`) is a shorthand method for forcing a variable to be a Number. Only Number's `toString()` method will take a radix, String's will not. Also, your result will be in lowercase, so you might want to force it to uppercase using `toUpperCase()`:

```
function d2h(d) { return (+d).toString(16).toUpperCase(); }
```

So the result will be:

```
d2h("28") //is "1C"
```

Comment: thanks, that is what I was doing wrong, it was a string not a number.

Comment: Instead of unary `+` you can also use Number as a function: `Number(d).toString(16)`, which might be better for maintenance as it's a bit more obvious what is occurring. Or not.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @RobG about the ambiguous nature of `+`, but in this case, we're performing a simple, one-line helper function that has a very obvious purpose in life and can be effectively treated as a black box by any future developers, so maintainability is not really a concern. If this were a line of code in the middle of a larger, more complex method, I would certainly suggest using the Number constructor for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate question

```
(28).toString(16)
```

The bug you are making is that "28" is a string, not a number. You should treat it as a number. One should not generally expect the language to be able to parse a string into an integer before doing conversions (well... I guess it's reasonable to expect the other way around in javascript).

Comment: it returns 28 and not 1C, not sure what you mean by Duplicate question as I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Aaron: no, it returns "1C". You should copy-paste the above line.

Answer (score 0):

d2h() as written should work fine:

```
js> var d=28
js> print(d.toString(16))
1c
```

How did you test it?

Also, 40 is the expected output of d2h(28), since hexadecimal "28" is decimal 40.

Answer (score 0):

```
let returnedHex = Number(var_value).toString(16);
```

also works