# Convert rgb strings to hex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

I am using the TweenMax JS library with the ColorPropsPlugin which will tween color values which are specified in many formats, the problem I have is that the result is always in the form of a string:

```
"rgb(255,255,255)"
```

How can that be converted in to a hex number like:

```
0xffffff
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: Don't think so as this question asks for a conversion of a string, not three integers. Or did I got it wrong?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would at first cut away the CSS parts:

```
var a = "rgb(255,255,255)".split("(")[1].split(")")[0];
```

Then split it into separate numbers:

```
a = a.split(",");
```

Convert the single numbers to hex

```
var b = a.map(function(x){             //For each array element
    x = parseInt(x).toString(16);      //Convert to a base16 string
    return (x.length==1) ? "0"+x : x;  //Add zero if we get only one character
})
```

And glue it back together:

```
b = "0x"+b.join("");
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong here, but would you check this does work please as I'm getting 0x255255255 - http://jsfiddle.net/QRk6J/1/

Comment: ok I figured it out, I have to create a new var for the map, eg: var b = a.map etc. I'll edit your answer - http://jsfiddle.net/QRk6J/2/

Comment: Here (Opera), it works with the same var. But good to know, thanks!

Comment: As a function, var a = str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1).split(',') works very well because parseInt will ignore the ')' in the last element.  No need for a pair of split calls.

Answer (score 14):

The following is adapted from a `Colour` class I wrote and use but may be overkill for your needs since it handles percentages and negative numbers.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5ryxx/1/

Code:

```
function componentFromStr(numStr, percent) {
    var num = Math.max(0, parseInt(numStr, 10));
    return percent ?
        Math.floor(255 * Math.min(100, num) / 100) : Math.min(255, num);
}

function rgbToHex(rgb) {
    var rgbRegex = /^rgb\(\s*(-?\d+)(%?)\s*,\s*(-?\d+)(%?)\s*,\s*(-?\d+)(%?)\s*\)$/;
    var result, r, g, b, hex = "";
    if ( (result = rgbRegex.exec(rgb)) ) {
        r = componentFromStr(result[1], result[2]);
        g = componentFromStr(result[3], result[4]);
        b = componentFromStr(result[5], result[6]);

        hex = "0x" + (0x1000000 + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Comment: I don't need percentages in this case, but as percentages are used in other cases I'll +1 you.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I did.

```
String.prototype.toRGB = function() {

  var rgb = this.split( ',' ) ;
  this.r=parseInt( rgb[0].substring(4) ) ; // skip rgb(
  this.g=parseInt( rgb[1] ) ; // this is just g
  this.b=parseInt( rgb[2] ) ; // parseInt scraps trailing )

}
```

After you run `'rgb(125,181,215)'.toRGB()`, you will get `.r`, `.g` and `.b` properties defined (with correct integer values) in the same string object returned.

To get the hex value, simply use [`yourNumber.toString(16);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

```js
rgb2Hex = s => s.match(/[0-9]+/g).reduce((a, b) => a+(b|256).toString(16).slice(1), '0x')

console.log(rgb2Hex('rgb(10, 11, 12)'), rgb2Hex('rgb(255, 256, 257)'))
```

---

Not recommended for unreliable user input, but the string can also be evaluated as a function:

```js
rgb = (r, g, b) => '0x' + (1<<24|r<<16|g<<8|b).toString(16).slice(1)

console.log(eval('rgb(10, 11, 12)'), eval('rgb(255)'))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function parseColor(color) {
    var arr=[]; color.replace(/[\d+\.]+/g, function(v) { arr.push(parseFloat(v)); });
    return {
        hex: "#" + arr.slice(0, 3).map(toHex).join(""),
        opacity: arr.length == 4 ? arr[3] : 1
    };
}
function toHex(int) {
    var hex = int.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}
```

---

```
parseColor("rgb(210, 10, 10)");  // {"hex":"#d20a0a","opacity":1}
parseColor("rgba(210, 10, 10, 0.5)"); // {"hex":"#d20a0a","opacity":"0.5"}
parseColor("rgb(210)");  // {"hex":"#d2","opacity":1}
```

Comment: It supports both rgb() and rgba().

Comment: does not handle decimal rgb   console.log(JSON.stringify(parseColor("rgb(251.94,247.35,221.85)") ) );   {"hex":"#fb.f0a3d70a3d7f7.599999999998dd.d99999999998","opacity":1}

Answer (score 2):

```
RGBToHex = function(r,g,b){
    var bin = r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
    return (function(h){
        return new Array(7-h.length).join("0")+h
    })(bin.toString(16).toUpperCase())
}
```

https://gist.github.com/lrvick/2080648

Edited:

```
cnvrtRGBClrToHex('255,145,20')

function cnvrtRGBClrToHex(rgbClr){
    var rgbClr = rgbClr.split(',');
    var r = rgbClr[0];
    var g = rgbClr[1];
    var b = rgbClr[2];
    return (r << 16 | g << 8 | b).toString(16).toUpperCase()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A codegolfed approach:

```
var h = x => '#' + x.match(/\d+/g).map(y = z => ((+z < 16)?'0':'') + (+z).toString(16)).join('');
```

Now, running `h("rgb(255, 60, 60)")` will return `#ff3c3c`.

You can replace `'#'` with `'0x'` to get outputs in the form of `0xff3c3c`.

*EXTRA: how it works.*

`h`, declared as an arrow function (new in ES6) takes an RGB value (string) and stores it in `x`.
Then, all instances of numbers in `x` are found by the regex equation `/\d+/g`, and used further as an array (returned by `match`, used by `map`).

`map` loops processes all the elements of the returned array by a function `y`.
The function takes a value (which was stored in the array as a string) as `z` converts it to a number (`+z`), checks if it is less than 16 (`((+z < 16)?'0':'')`, that is, the hex representation has a single digit), and if true, adds a `'0'` to the element's start.

Then, it converts it to a string of base 16 (hex, by `.toString(16)`), and returns it to `map`. So essentially, all the decimal strings in the array are now changed to hex strings.

Finally, the array's elements are joined together (`join('')`), with no delimiter and `'#'` is added to the beginning of the string.

**Note: If the code is supplied a value greater than 255, the output will be more than 6 hex digits. Like, the output for `rgb(256, 0, 0)` will be `#1000000`.**

To constraint the value to 255, this would be the code:

```
var h = x => '#' + x.match(/\d+/g).map(y = z => ((+z < 16)?'0':'') + ((+z > 255)?255:+z).toString(16)).join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

A readable oneliner for rgb string to hex string:

```
rgb = "rgb(0,128,255)"
hex = '#' + rgb.slice(4,-1).split(',').map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join('')
```

which returns here `"#0080ff"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to convert from RGB color to HEX in JavaScript

```
    color = "rgb(51,51,51);";
    color = '#'+color.match(/\d+/g).map(function(x){
        x = parseInt(x).toString(16);
        return (x.length==1) ? "0"+x : x;
    }).join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this code block to convert RGB color to hexadecimal color in TypeScript and JavaScript. **Note**: It converts to float and non-float values in the RGB color:

**TypeScript code**:

```
function parseFloat(value?: string): number {
  if (!value || Number.isNaN(value)) return -1;

  return Number.parseFloat(value);
}

function isRgbNumber(numberColor: number): boolean {
  if (numberColor !== 0 && !numberColor) return false;

  const MIN_NUMBER_COLOR = 0;
  const MAX_NUMBER_COLOR = 255;

  return numberColor >= MIN_NUMBER_COLOR && numberColor <= MAX_NUMBER_COLOR;
}

function rgbToHexadecimal(rgbColor: string): string | null {
  const LENGTH_OF_RGB_COLOR = 3;

  const regexToRemoveCharacters = /[A-Z()\s]/gi;
  const redGreenAndBlueNumbers = rgbColor
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(regexToRemoveCharacters, '')
    .split(',');

  if (redGreenAndBlueNumbers.length !== LENGTH_OF_RGB_COLOR) return null;

  const [red, green, blue] = redGreenAndBlueNumbers;
  const allColorsExists = !!red && !!green && !!blue;
  if (!allColorsExists) return null;

  const redNumber = parseFloat(red);
  const greenNumber = parseFloat(green);
  const blueNumber = parseFloat(blue);

  if (
    !isRgbNumber(redNumber) ||
    !isRgbNumber(greenNumber) ||
    !isRgbNumber(blueNumber)
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  const byteNumbers =
    (1 << 24) | (redNumber << 16) | (greenNumber << 8) | blueNumber;

  return '#' + byteNumbers.toString(16).slice(1).toUpperCase();
}

console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(0, 0, 0)')); // "#000000" 
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(16, 16, 16)')); // "#101010" 
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(128, 128, 128)')); // "#808080" 
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(245, 255, 255)')); // "#F5FFFF"
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(2.55, 10.17, 123.876)')); // "#020A7B"
```

**JavaScript code**:

```js
function parseFloat(value) {
  if (!value || Number.isNaN(value)) return -1;

  return Number.parseFloat(value);
}

function isRgbNumber(numberColor) {
  if (numberColor !== 0 && !numberColor) return false;

  const MIN_NUMBER_COLOR = 0;
  const MAX_NUMBER_COLOR = 255;

  return numberColor >= MIN_NUMBER_COLOR && numberColor <= MAX_NUMBER_COLOR;
}

function rgbToHexadecimal(rgbColor) {
  const LENGTH_OF_RGB_COLOR = 3;

  const regexToRemoveCharacters = /[A-Z()\s]/gi;
  const redGreenAndBlueNumbers = rgbColor
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(regexToRemoveCharacters, '')
    .split(',');

  if (redGreenAndBlueNumbers.length !== LENGTH_OF_RGB_COLOR) return null;

  const [red, green, blue] = redGreenAndBlueNumbers;
  const allColorsExists = !!red && !!green && !!blue;
  if (!allColorsExists) return null;

  const redNumber = parseFloat(red);
  const greenNumber = parseFloat(green);
  const blueNumber = parseFloat(blue);

  if (
    !isRgbNumber(redNumber) ||
    !isRgbNumber(greenNumber) ||
    !isRgbNumber(blueNumber)
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  const byteNumbers =
    (1 << 24) | (redNumber << 16) | (greenNumber << 8) | blueNumber;

  return '#' + byteNumbers.toString(16).slice(1).toUpperCase();
}

console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(0, 0, 0)')); // "#000000" 
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(16, 16, 16)')); // "#101010" 
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(128, 128, 128)')); // "#808080" 
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(245, 255, 255)')); // "#F5FFFF"
console.log(rgbToHexadecimal('rgb(2.55, 10.17, 123.876)')); // "#020A7B"
```