# converting RGB to HEX issue

Tags: javascript, converters

according to one of StackOverflow topics I tried to create own RGB to HEX colors converter.

I don't know why but instead converting it double RGB numbers.

So when input is `rgb(0, 128, 192)` it console out `#00128192`.

My code is:

```
fromRGB: {
    toHEX: {
        supportFunc: function(number) {
            var hex = number.toString(16);
            return hex.length == 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
        },
        convert: function(r, g, b) {
            var lol = '#' + this.supportFunc(r) + this.supportFunc(g) + this.supportFunc(b);
            console.log(lol);
        }
    },
    prepareAndExecute: function(color_field) {
        // preparing
        var numbers = color_field.match(/\d+/g);
        if(numbers.length == 3) {
            this.toHEX.convert(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]);
        } else {
            alert('wrong RGB number format');
        }


        //this.toHSL(preparedValue);
    }
}
```

I execute prepare function, `lol` variable is the one that should contains converted color in HEX format.

What is wrong with my code, why it doesn't work?

Comment: `.match()` returns an array of **strings**, not numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: @KenWhite I think OP already used that duplicate link to come up with his code above. But he encountered a problem (strings as numbers) that is not related to how to get the values. Thus marking it as duplicate to that link is wrong.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Then the poster didn't properly use the code from the linked post and should go back and read it again. It's still a duplicate of the basic question, which is *Converting RGB to HEX in Javascript*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert rgb strings to hex in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070054/convert-rgb-strings-to-hex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

It's because you're passing strings not numbers to `supportFunc`.

The result of `match` in `prepareAndExecute` is an array of strings, thus when you call `toString` in `supportFunc`, you are calling `String.prototype.toString` (not `Number.prototype.toString`) which return the string as is.

**Solution:**

In `supportFunc`, convert `number` to a number before using `toString`:

```
var hex = Number(number).toString(16);                       // using Number to convert a string to a number (you can use parseInt or unary + if you like)
```

or convert them before passing them to `convert`:

```
this.toHEX.convert(+numbers[0], +numbers[1], +numbers[2]);   // using unary +
```