# How to check with puppeteer or playwright if an element is of a specific color?

Tags: puppeteer, playwright

I have an element that has this style   color: #dc7709   and I want to check if that element's text is of that color. How do I do that with Puppeteer or playwright?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Notice that it will return an `rgb` value:

```
 assert(await page.$eval('span', e => getComputedStyle(e).color)).toBe('rgb(220, 119, 9)');
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how we should use it when we need the color after the **:hover** css effect ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(await page.$eval('span', e => getComputedStyle(e).caretColor)).toBe('rgb(220, 119, 9)');
```

The above can also be used, change the rgb value as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy-loading styles, wait for the stylesheet to load first:

```js
// playwright.spec.ts

test.only('should style alert messages', async ({ page }) => {
  const alert = page.locator('.alert-primary').first();
  const initialColor = await alert.evaluate((el) => {
    return getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
  });
  console.log(initialColor);

  await page.waitForResponse(
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  );
  const styledColor = await alert.evaluate((el) => getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor);
  console.log(styledColor);
});
```

As the `initialColor` and `styledColor` may differ:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
rgb(212, 237, 218)
```

You can then [convert to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13070198/712334) for your test assertion:

```js
expect(rgbToHex(styledColor) === '#dc7709');
```