# Deleting a contact/person from Google Contacts by using its resourceName - retreived from a Cell in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

```
GOAL: 
What i want to achieve is that i can pick in a list of resourceNames a specific resourceName and when i run the function in the (special) menu of my GoogleSheet, the selected resourceName is used to delete the person in the Google Contacts

person in googlesheet
```

[image]

I have activated the Peopleapi as a service - in the code editor.

When i run the function i get this message: "person with the resourceName "xxx" does not exits in "

[image]  I wrote these functions, i expected that the person with the corresponding resourceName woule be deleted from the GoogleContacts.

```
`function deletePerson() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var resourceNameColumn = 1;  // Column A
  var resourceNameRow = 2;     // Start row 2

  // get the resourceName form the cell in the sheet
  var resourceName = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow, resourceNameColumn).getValue();
  // var resourceName = "person/c4736325340303186435"
  //"person/c4736325340303186435";

  // Search for the person with the given resourceName in the People API
  var contactPerson = searchContactPerson(resourceName);

  if (contactPerson) {
    // if the person is found, get the unstructuredName en delete the person 
    var unstructuredName = contactPerson.names[0].unstructuredName;
    deleteContactPersoon(contactPerson.resourceName);
    
    // Give a message to the user that the person is deleted
    Browser.msgBox('Succes', 'Person with unstructuredName "' + unstructuredName + '" is deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  } else {
    // Giver a message to the user if the person is not found
    Browser.msgBox('Not Okay', 'Person with the resourceName "' + resourceName + '" does not exists als contactperson.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}

// Function to find the contactperson by means of the resourceName
function searchContactPerson(resourceName) {
//  var contacten = People.People.Connections.list('people/me').connections;
  var contacts = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
      //personFields: 'names,emailAddresses,addresses,resourceName,birthdays,phoneNumbers,urls,organizations,biographies'
      personFields: 'names'});
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].resourceName == resourceName) {
      return contacts[i];
    }
  }
  return null; // Return null if person is not found
}

// Function to delete the contactperson by means of the resourceName
function deleteContactPerson(resourceName) {
  People.People.Connections.deleteContact(resourceName);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In the case of "Method: people.connections.list", the property of `resourceName` is in an array `connections`. So, in this case, your function `searchContactPerson` is required to be as follows. I guessed that the reason for your 1st issue is due to this.

  ```js
  function searchContactPerson(resourceName) {
    var contacts = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', { personFields: 'names' });
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.connections.length; i++) {
      if (contacts.connections[i].resourceName == resourceName) {
        return contacts.connections[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  ```
- In your showing script, `deleteContactPersoon` of `deleteContactPersoon(contactPerson.resourceName)` is not declared. So, when your script is run, an error occurs at this line. I think that this is your 2nd issue.
- In order to delete a contact, `People.People.Connections.deleteContact(resourceName)` is required to be modified to `People.People.deleteContact(resourceName);`. I think that this is your 3rd issue.
- In order to search the contact using `resourceName`, I thought that "Method: people.getBatchGet" might be able to be used. In this case, it is not required to use a loop.

#### Modified script 1:

When your showing script is modified it becomes as follows.

```js
function deletePerson() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var resourceNameColumn = 1;  // Column A
  var resourceNameRow = 2;     // Start row 2

  // get the resourceName form the cell in the sheet
  var resourceName = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow, resourceNameColumn).getValue();

  // Search for the person with the given resourceName in the People API
  var contactPerson = searchContactPerson(resourceName);
  if (contactPerson) {
    // if the person is found, get the unstructuredName en delete the person 
    var unstructuredName = contactPerson.names[0].unstructuredName;
    deleteContactPerson(contactPerson.resourceName);

    // Give a message to the user that the person is deleted
    Browser.msgBox('Succes', 'Person with unstructuredName "' + unstructuredName + '" is deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  } else {
    // Giver a message to the user if the person is not found
    Browser.msgBox('Not Okay', 'Person with the resourceName "' + resourceName + '" does not exists als contactperson.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}

// Function to find the contactperson by means of the resourceName
function searchContactPerson(resourceName) {
  var contacts = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', { personFields: 'names' });
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.connections.length; i++) {
    if (contacts.connections[i].resourceName == resourceName) {
      return contacts.connections[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Function to delete the contactperson by means of the resourceName
function deleteContactPerson(resourceName) {
  People.People.deleteContact(resourceName);
}
```

- When this script is run, when `resourceName` is existing, the contact of `resourceName` is deleted. Please be careful about this.

#### Modified script 2:

As another approach, when the method for searching a contact using `resourceName` is changed, it becomes as follows.

```js
function deletePerson() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var resourceNameColumn = 1;  // Column A
  var resourceNameRow = 2;     // Start row 2
  var resourceName = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow, resourceNameColumn).getValue();
  var contactPerson = searchContactPerson(resourceName);
  if (contactPerson) {
    deleteContactPerson(resourceName);
    Browser.msgBox('Succes', 'Person with unstructuredName "' + contactPerson + '" is deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox('Not Okay', 'Person with the resourceName "' + resourceName + '" does not exists als contactperson.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}

function searchContactPerson(resourceName) {
  var res = People.People.getBatchGet({ personFields: "names", resourceNames: [resourceName] }).responses[0];
  return res.httpStatusCode == 200 ? res.person?.names[0]?.unstructuredName : false;
}

function deleteContactPerson(resourceName) {
  People.People.deleteContact(resourceName);
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)
- [Method: people.getBatchGet](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet)

### Added:

From the following reply,

> You wrote "the value of the resourceName is required to be people/###" See: my remark at "Second try i changed the value of person" I obtained the value (contacts.google.com/person/cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ) from the Google Contacts.

I understood that your value of `sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow, resourceNameColumn).getValue()` is like `person/c###`. Unfortunately, this cannot be directly used with People API. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, it is required to convert `person/c###` to `people/c###`. When this is reflected in my 2nd script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
// ref: https://medium.com/google-cloud/convert-contact-url-to-resource-name-for-people-api-using-google-apps-script-96457e6f9597
function convertPersonToPeople_(person) {
  if (!(/^person\/c[\d]*$/).test(person)) {
    throw new Error("Invalid value.");
  }

  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668344
  function dec2hex(str) { // .toString(16) only works up to 2^53
    var dec = str.toString().split(''), sum = [], hex = [], i, s
    while (dec.length) {
      s = 1 * dec.shift()
      for (i = 0; s || i < sum.length; i++) {
        s += (sum[i] || 0) * 10
        sum[i] = s % 16
        s = (s - sum[i]) / 16
      }
    }
    while (sum.length) {
      hex.push(sum.pop().toString(16))
    }
    return hex.join('')
  }

  // Convert decimal to hexadecimal.
  const hexadecimalValue = dec2hex(person.replace("person/c", ""));

  // Search contact.
  let res = null;
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const obj = People.People.Connections.list("people/me", { personFields: "emailAddresses", pageSize: 1000, pageToken });
    if (obj.connections.length > 0) {
      const t = obj.connections.find(c => c.emailAddresses.some(e => e.metadata.source.id == hexadecimalValue));
      if (t) {
        res = t;
        break;
      }
    }
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  if (!res) return;

  // Return resource name.
  const { resourceName } = res;
  return resourceName;
}

function deletePerson() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var resourceNameColumn = 1;  // Column A
  var resourceNameRow = 2;     // Start row 2
  var personValue = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow, resourceNameColumn).getValue();

  // Convert from person/c### to people/c###
  var resourceName = convertPersonToPeople_(personValue);

  var contactPerson = searchContactPerson(resourceName);
  if (contactPerson) {
    deleteContactPerson(resourceName);
    Browser.msgBox('Succes', 'Person with unstructuredName "' + contactPerson + '" is deleted.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox('Not Okay', 'Person with the resourceName "' + resourceName + '" does not exists als contactperson.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}

function searchContactPerson(resourceName) {
  var res = People.People.getBatchGet({ personFields: "names", resourceNames: [resourceName] }).responses[0];
  return res.httpStatusCode == 200 ? res.person?.names[0]?.unstructuredName : false;
}

function deleteContactPerson(resourceName) {
  People.People.deleteContact(resourceName);
}
```

Please run the function `deletePerson`. When this script is run, `person/c###` is converted to `people/c###` and the contact is deleted using `people/c###`.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply. I have been very busy lately so i have not been able to look into your solutions. Hopefully i find the time tomorrow. If so: i will test and give my conclusions

Comment: Hi Tanaike: i put my comment on your solutions - because the did not work - as an answer, because i did not have enough space for my conclusions in one comment. Can you look to those conclusions?  Much appreciated!

Comment: @M. Atou Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. But, unfortunately, when I tested my script, no error occurred. But, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my very poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation from your posted answer. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue?

Comment: @M. Atou By the way, you are posing your question as an answer. Please remove it.

Comment: Hi, please do not apologize. I have the same. I tried Modified script 2 code
First i tried the function,  cellvalue was: "person/c4743598880287259382"
Logger.log() > "Searchstring = person/c4743598880287259382"
That is OK. But then  i got this messages
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
searchContactPerson @ Code.gs:154
deletePerson @ Code.gs:142

codeline 154 =  "var res = People.People.getBatchGet({personFields: "names", resourceNames:[resourceName]}.response[0]);"
codeline 142 =  "var contactPerson = searchContactPerson(resourceName); "

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Second try
i changed the value of person/c4743598880287259382 to people/c4743598880287259382
SO in stead of **person/cxxx**, i used **people/cxxx**
But the execution of the function did not succeed.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
searchContactPerson @ Code.gs:154
deletePerson @ Code.gs:142

codeline 154 =  "var res = People.People.getBatchGet({personFields: "names", resourceNames:[resourceName]}.response[0]);"
codeline 142 =  "var contactPerson = searchContactPerson(resourceName); "

Result: is got the same TypeError

Comment: Hi Tanaike. you wrote "By the way, you are posing your question as an answer.". I tried to do that but it seems removed by the moderator (?)

Comment: @M. Atou Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill, again. I proposed 2 modified scripts. But, from your reply, I cannot understand which did you use? Can I ask you about the details of it? By the way, in both scripts, the value of the resourceName is required to be `people/###`. It seems that from your reply, your resourceName might not be like that. How about this? And, where did you obtain it? I'm worried that I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @M. Atou About `you wrote "By the way, you are posing your question as an answer.". I tried to do that but it seems removed by the moderator (?) `, I understood it.

Comment: you wrote "I proposed 2 modified scripts."
I used your Modified Script 2, with these functions you proposed. 
function deletePerson()
function searchContactPerson(resourceName)
function deleteContactPerson(resourceName) 
You wrote "the value of the resourceName is required to be **people/###"**
See: my remark at "Second try i changed the value of person"
I obtained the value (https://contacts.google.com/person/cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ) from the Google Contacts. I use GoogleSheet with Appscript and the People (V1) as a Service. I do not know how else i can connect to People

Comment: @M. Atou Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added a modified script of my 2nd script in my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply (busy).I used you modified script, changed the beginning of the code to 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var personValue = "person/c8399003111647802141";
I exec. your proposed function: it did not work
Somehow this part: " const t = obj.connections.find(c => c.emailAddresses.some(e => e.metadata.source.id == hexadecimalValue));"
gives Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some').
Found a solution: can i mail it to y or can y advice me how to post it here? Do not know how to do that. Thanks

Comment: I have this remark for this part of the solution: function convertPersonToPeople_(person).  
Why not simlipify this function into a line of code in the function deletePerson()? 

`var resourceName = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow,resourceNameColumn).getValue();
  var Name = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow,NameColumn).getValue();
  var modifiedResourceName = "people/" + resourceName.substring(7).replace(/\s/g, '');`

This results that the value
**"person/c8399003111647802141"** is now 
**"people/c8399003111647802141"**.

Comment: @M. Atou Thank you for replying. About `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')`, in this case, it is considered that the email address is not included. Please confirm it. About your 2nd reply, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: I am rather busy these days, i will try to get back to you next week :)

Comment: (Busy with coming EU2024 elections.) 
I do not get understand this part of your reply "in this case, it is considered that the email address is not included. Please confirm it". The value "person/c8399003111647802141" is corresponding with "Frans van Elders", his email is "elders@gmail.com". So what do you mean?

Comment: About my 2nd Reply. See this solution (divided in 2 comments:
First part

`function deleteContactA(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var resourceNameColumn = 1;
  var NameColumn = 2;
  var resourceNameRow = Browser.inputBox("Bepaal rijnummer van Contactpersoon", "Voer het nummer van de rij in:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
.. error handling  
  
  var resourceName = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow,resourceNameColumn).getValue();
  var Name = sheet.getRange(resourceNameRow,NameColumn).getValue(); `

Comment: About my 2nd Reply. See this solution (divided in 2 comments:
Second part

`var modifiedResourceName = "people/" + resourceName.substring(7).replace(/\s/g, '');
  var people = People.People.getBatchGet(
    {
    resourceNames: modifiedResourceName,
    personFields: 'metadata'
  });
// Next line deletes the person from Google Contact.
    People.People.deleteContact(modifiedResourceName);
   sheet.deleteRow(resourceNameRow);
    Browser.msgBox('Succes','Person with the Name"'+ Name +'"is deleted from Google Contacts.',Browser.Buttons.OK);
} `

Comment: @M. Atou Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your replies. Can I ask you about the details of your replies? Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurred. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again.