# jQuery to get value of input field where string contains brackets?

Tags: jquery

I have a form input field where some of the input string contains brackets, such as:

```
ducks[quack]
```

Note that this is not the name, class, anything like that. This is the value.

When I attempt to select this value with jquery, using the field class and val(), it returns an empty object. The same field with a string without brackets as the value, is selected fine.

I cannot modify the dataset which contains the brackets, is there some way to enable jquery to pull the value for these fields of strings?

http://jsfiddle.net/V8XP2/10/

Comment: Please post your HTML and the JS code you are using to retrieve the value.

Comment: Can you provide your actual code/markup or a demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach works, using the attribute-equals notation:

```
jQuery('#create_suborder').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var product = jQuery('#products').val(),
        product_id = jQuery('input[id="product_id_' + product + '"]').val(),
        total_units = jQuery('input[id="total_units_' + product + '"]').val();

    console.log(product, product_id, total_units);

    jQuery('#result').html(product_id + ', ' + total_units);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/V8XP2/12/).

Though using CSS notation: `#product_id_' + product` does not; I'm assuming that this is due to the need to escape `[` and `]` in CSS, which should be a back-slash, followed by the unicode character-point of the relevant characters. This is in contrast to the attribute-equals approach, which finds the elements and then iterates through the named attribute for the string-value supplied to the selector.

After some revision, the following works:

```
jQuery('#create_suborder').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var product = jQuery('#products').val().replace(/\[|\]/g, function(a){
        return '\\' + a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + ' ';
    }),
        product_id = jQuery('#product_id_' + product).val(),
        total_units = jQuery('#total_units_' + product).val();

    jQuery('#result').html(product_id + ', ' + total_units);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/V8XP2/14/).

This retrieves the value of the `select` element, then replaces any (and all) `[` and `]` characters, using the anonymous function of the `replace()` method. In this function `a` is the character that was found.

We return the string that begins with two `\\` characters (since the `\` is otherwise an escape character, and we want the literal `\`, we have to escape the escape); we concatenate that with the character-code of the found character (`a.charCodeAt()`) and, because CSS requires the Unicode character-points to be in hexadecimal format, we use `toString(16)` to convert from the decimal Unicode (`91` and `93`) to the hexadecimal format (`5b` and `5d`); we then append a space as well, in order to delimit/end the escaped character-sequence.

References:

- Stack Overflow:

  - [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)
- JavaScript:

  - [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).
  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString).
- jQuery:

  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).