# Make color code of any six digit

Tags: html, css, colors

I have six digit random number like 1424517,1420422 and so on. Is there any way to use this number to make html color code and i used it as background:#1424517 to make some background color.

Comment: Do you want to ask how to change color randomly every time you load a page?

Comment: Looks like your 6 digit numbers have 7 digits

Comment: You can put a “#” before a six-digit sequence to produce a color code. So what is the problem?

Comment: You can calculate a hash from that value and use that as Color. You can build a really big Color Array und use your value as an index into the table. You can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

CSS color codes are 8bit-RGB by default. I assume, you have a single 24-bit number. You can simply convert it to a CSS color code, by [formatting it as hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript).

If you have 3 8-bit numbers, you can construct a number like this:

```
color = (val1 % 256, val2 % 256, val3 % 256);
```

Where "%" is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking, but I'm assuming that you want to randomly select a color for a webpage. Colors are done in RGB Hexadecimal typically, ranging from #000000 (black) to #FFFFFF (white). #0000FF would be pure blue, #00FF00 would be pure green, and #FF0000 would be pure red. By changing the values you will have different colors. You could always generate a random number between 0 and 16777215 (256^3-1) and convert that to hex.

Answer (score 0):

html color codes can be in 3 formats:

- hex value(#123abc)
- rgb which ranges from 0-255, rgb(100,100,100), and
- direct name of the colors(eg: red, green blue)

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp