# What's wrong with my Ip to hex equation in javascript? Output doesn't match other sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip, hex

Code, give item is a valid ip (i.e. 254.253.242.222 )

```
     `var h0 = Math.pow(256,0);`
 `var h1 = Math.pow(256,1);`
    `var h2 = Math.pow(256,2);`
```

`var h3 = Math.pow(256,3);`

```
    var splitup = item.split('.');       var iHex =  (splitup[3] * h0) + (splitup[2] * h1) + (splitup[1]* h2) + (splitup[0] * h3) ;
    var hhexip = parseInt(iHex,16);
    $('#hexip').val($('#hexip').val() + "0x" + hhexip +"\n" );
```

this site http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/ipconverter.php?convert_from=254.253.242.222

*edit*

fixed code to use math.pow... still getting wrong out put though.
says it should be
0xFEFDF2DE

but i get 0x285481457222

help?

Comment: `^` is the bitwise xor operation in JavaScript. Try `256^3` and see what you get (answer: 259).

Comment: essentially a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item = "254.253.242.222";
var splitup = item.split('.');
var iHex = parseInt(splitup[0]).toString(16) + parseInt(splitup[1]).toString(16) + parseInt(splitup[2]).toString(16) + parseInt(splitup[3]).toString(16);
var hhexip = parseInt(iHex,16);
$('#hexip').val($('#hexip').val() + "0x" + hhexip +"\n" );
```