# increment html hexadecimal character codes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I have this `HTML`:

```
<ul>
    <li data-icon="&#xe00a;">1</li>
</ul>
```

And `CSS`:

```
[data-icon]:before {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    ...
}
```

I would like to increment this value `&#xe00a;`. Is the next logical progression of this value `&#xe00b`? And so on until `&#xe00f;`,`&#xe01a;`,`&#xe01b;`, etc.?

Edit:

The purpose is to traverse the entirety of the font icon collection I'm working with.

Comment: are you trying to do this increment in css?

Comment: @depperm No, Javascript as the title states.

Comment: so what have you tried so far? There is no js here.

Comment: @depperm It's not necessary. How do I take this value `&#xe00a;` and use javascript to increment to the next logical step? I don't understand how it works which is why I don't have js code. My attempt at understanding it is right below my `CSS`.

Comment: what format is that value? It isn't hexadecimal

Comment: @depperm I believe it is `HTML hexadecimal`, but I'm not sure. http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp

Comment: One idea is `parseInt` the hexadecimal part `++` then use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript to convert it back to hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how many icons you are dealing with?  If your sole purpose is to view them in a list, you can do so with some simple jQuery.

Check out this fiddle for some inspiration: https://jsfiddle.net/bps3Lrcf/

As you can see, `(parseInt("e00a", 16) + i).toString(16)` will increment the value as you've asked.