# Generate rainbow colors based on value

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I am trying to generate rainbow colors based on the numeric value.

```
var max = 10000;
var min = 0;
var val = 8890;

function getcolor(min,max,val) {
     // return red - black;
 }
```

**colors**
Red
Yellow
Green
Blue
Black (value == 0)

Like in the url https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRevs.jpg

From the above values how to generate color between red - black. High value is red and low value is black.

Comment: convert them to hexadecimal? try this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Comment: No, I want to generate color code based on the value, max, min.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's just a couple things you need to do and understand in order to accomplish this task. The first is realizing that the RGB colourspace is not the one you want for this task - the HSV or HSL ones are far better. Since the browsers are happy to work with HSL, we'll use that one.

Next, if you look at the H channel of the HSL colourspace, you can see that the exact band of colours you want is present there. The blue has a hue of about 240° and the red has one of 0­°.

This means that we want to map the range of [min..max] to the Hues of [240..0] (yes, the mapping is 'backwards')
With this in mind, we can set about creating a function that will do the mapping for us and return a valid colour string.

```
function calcColor(min, max, val)
{
    var minHue = 240, maxHue=0;
    var curPercent = (val - min) / (max-min);
    var colString = "hsl(" + ((curPercent * (maxHue-minHue) ) + minHue) + ",100%,50%)";
    return colString;
}
```

First, we setup the two end-points of the Hues that we wish to use. 
Next, we work out where abouts in the current range the current value is.
Finally, we put ourselves in the same position relatively speaking, in the Hue range instead of the user-input range.

A simple, example of its use is shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        var elem = newEl('div');
        elem.style.backgroundColor = calcColor(0, 9, i);
        elem.className = "rgb";
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
    }
}

function calcColor(min, max, val)
{
    var minHue = 240, maxHue=0;
    var curPercent = (val - min) / (max-min);
    var colString = "hsl(" + ((curPercent * (maxHue-minHue) ) + minHue) + ",100%,50%)";
    return colString;
}

</script>
<style>
.rgb
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi enhzflep, how would i change the code in order to include black and white colors in the extremes? I tried changing "calcColor" parameters and "Hue" but nothing, I keep getting from blue to red.

Comment: @Jose - Since these would be false colours, I really don't know what to suggest - some ways of faking them will be suitable for you, others wont. If you wish to blend into them, it makes it even harder. Perhaps you simply need to work with a palette?

Answer (score 1):

make some proportions:

if you got `max - min` range, and you want to vary colors from black to red as u described, just divide your range in 6 phases:

first 1/4: R G B values are `(0, 0, 0)` at lower value and `(0, 0, 255)` at higher, so you'll have graduation from black to blue..

second 1/4: from `(0, 0, 255)` to `(0, 255, 0)` so you'll have graduation from blue to green

third 1/4: from `(0, 255, 0)` to `(255, 255, 0)` and that's the yellow

last 1/4: from `(255, 255, 0)` to `(255, 0, 0)` and here's red.

use proportion to determine intermediate values.

Enjoy :), here's a little explanation in terms of code...

https://jsfiddle.net/4cq8fqjg/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

use this library.
https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor

calculate the percentage of your value based on you max value.

run the script with that value.

```
tinycolor("hsv (_CALCULATED PERCENTAGE_ 100% 100%)");
```

Comment: I tried it, it only generating red and green colors.