# Javascript convert hex to 32 bit integer

Tags: javascript, integer, hex, 32-bit

I have task to work with colors. From API i got color Argb value (as i understood it's an 32 bit integer value), for example -65536, which i convert to hex using next function:

```
argbToHex: function(color) {
    return '#'+ ('000000' + (color & 0xFFFFFF).toString(16)).slice(-6);
}
```

as resalt i'm getting hex color number:

```
#ff0000
```

but i need to do reverse operation, convert this hex back to Argb format with result:

```
-65536
```

i tried do something like that:

```
function (hex){
    let parsedHex = hex.replace('#', '0x');
    return parseInt(hex, 32);
}
```

and lot's of other variants, but nothing gave me expected result.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help with your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Comment: works for me! thanks! but if i want convert to 32 bit, why parseInt(hex, 16); ? @domyos

Comment: parseInt takes the base of the input (the hex variable) as the second parameter not your desired output.