# Robust conversion of hexadecimal string to byte values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex, byte, converters

I try to extract the byte values from a string containing hexadecimal byte representations. The string also contains (unknown) non-hexadecimal characters which needs to be ignored (delimiters, whitespace formatting).

Given an input string `"f5 df 45:f8 a 8 f53"`, the result would be the array `[245, 223, 69, 248, 168, 245]`. Note that byte values are only output from two hexadecimal digits (hence, the last `3` is ignored).

As an additional constraint, the code needs to work in ecmascript 3 environments.

So far, I have used this approach:

```
function parseHex(hex){
    hex = hex.replace(/[^0-9a-fA-F]/g, '');
    var i, 
        len = hex.length, 
        bin = [];
    for(i = 0; i < len - 1; i += 2){
        bin.push(+('0x' + hex.substring(i, i + 2)));
    }
    return bin;
}
```

However, I feel that it would be possible to find a more elegant solution to this, so the question is:

Is there a better solution to this problem (that would perform better or solve the problem with less code)?

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can not find any question in your post.

Comment: @ceving, tried to clarify the question.

Comment: @ceving, tried to research whether this question should be posted to codereview instead, but I am not yet convinced that it is off-topic for SO. This [guide to code review for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) specifically advises: "Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that 'it belongs on Code Review'"

Answer (score 2):

## Updated answer (ES3)

Since you mentioned in the comment to my original answer that you're limited to ES3, you should just be able to do this then:

```
function parseHex(string) {
  // remove all non-hex characters, and then separate them into an array in groups of 2 characters
  var arr = string.replace(/[^0-9a-fA-F]/g, '').match(/[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g);

  // mutate the array in-place with the correct decimal values
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i], 16);
  }

  return arr;
}

parseHex('f5 df 45:f8 a 8 f53'); // => [245, 223, 69, 248, 168, 245]
```

It'll essentially do what `map` does, except it has less space complexity than `map` because it's mutating the array in place. See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/xozabi/edit?js,console,output).

## Previous answer (ES5)

You can do this (here's a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/wurexi/edit?js,console,output)):

```
'f5 df 45:f8 a 8 f53'.replace(/[^0-9a-fA-F]/g, '').match(/[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g).map(function(hex) {
  return parseInt(hex, 16);
});

// => [245, 223, 69, 248, 168, 245]
```

You can make it a function like this:

```
function parseHex(string) {
  return string.replace(/[^0-9a-fA-F]/g, '').match(/[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g).map(function(hex) {
    return parseInt(hex, 16);
  });
}

parseHex('f5 df 45:f8 a 8 f53');
```

Essentially you remove non-hex characters from the string, then match groups of two hex characters (as per your requirements). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805/2714730) describes the `parseInt(hex, 16)` portion (where the reverse would be `hex.toString(16)`).

Comment: That's a nice one-liner. Unfortunately, using `.map()` is not an option to me (ES3).

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to using `.match()` and mutating the array in place.

Comment: Sure, it worked fine. Your use of `.match()` led me to explore several regex approaches, but then I found a non-regex approach I liked even more.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Using regex methods lead to less code, but worse performance. A non-regex solution gives better performance, at the cost of slightly more code.

#### Regex approaches

After some more research/googling (and seeing [Josh Beams answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396866/6738706) use `.match()`), I figured that there are several possible regex approaches that could improve on the original approach.

Using `.match()` directly (without `.replace()`), inspired by [Josh Beams answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396866/6738706):

```
function parseHex(hex){
    hex = hex.match(/[\da-f]/gi);
    for(var i = 0; i < hex.length - 1; i += 2){
        hex[i >> 1] = +('0x' + hex[i] + hex[i + 1]);
    }
    hex.length = i >> 1;
    return hex;
}
```

Use `.replace()` for iteration (inspired by [this](https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques#use-replace-or-exec-for-powerful-string-iteration)):

```
function parseHex(hex){
    var bin = [];
    hex.replace(/([\da-f])[^\da-f]*([\da-f])/gi,
        function(m, digit1, digit2){
            bin.push(+('0x' + digit1 + digit2));
        }
    );
    return bin;
}
```

Looping with `.exec()` (also inspired by [this](https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques#use-replace-or-exec-for-powerful-string-iteration)):

```
function parseHex(hex){
    var bin = [],
        regex = /([\da-f])[^\da-f]*([\da-f])/gi,
        result;
    while(result = regex.exec(hex)){
        bin.push(+('0x' + result[1] + result[2]));
    }
    return bin;
}
```

#### Performance and a non-regex solution

After [running performance tests here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/107/4/parse-hex-to-bytes), none of the regex approaches seem to perform significantly better than the original approach. Out of curiosity, I attempted a non-regex solution, which significantly outperforms the other approaches (at the cost of slightly more code):

```
function parseHex(hex){
    var bin = [], i, c, isEmpty = 1, buffer;
    for(i = 0; i < hex.length; i++){
        c = hex.charCodeAt(i);
        if(c > 47 && c < 58 || c > 64 && c < 71 || c > 96 && c < 103){
            buffer = buffer << 4 ^ (c > 64 ? c + 9 : c) & 15;
            if(isEmpty ^= 1){
                bin.push(buffer & 0xff);
            }
        }
    }
    return bin;
}
```

I will probably go for the non-regex approach.