# Create decimal colours from HEX that start with a 0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, pixi.js

I have a bit of a problem that I am encountering with trying to convert a colour from a hex string into an integer value.

The reason that I am trying to achieve this, is that I am reading from a JSON that feeds in hex values that are then read by [Pixi](http://www.pixijs.com/) and standard Canvas elements to then give them their colours.

Now this will read and convert all my colours correctly until it hits one that starts with a 0 or for example 'black' which is only made up of 0's

```
parseInt("00aaa4", 16);//43684
```

This becomes an invalid number to be read by my canvas elements. Where as

```
parseInt("10aaa4", 16); //1092260
```

Is valid and will work fine. 
I am not sure if there is a simple work around for this problem. Tried looking for some NPM modules but they all give the same issue.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you expect this `00aaa4` to be when converted?

Comment: Well thats the thing I dont know what it will be, I know that it breaks and defaults to pixi black when a colour doesnt work or cant be found. So for example if i did a parseInt on 000000 it returns 0. From my understanding that is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to mark a number's type. Putting 0x before it makes it a hexadecimal number, but 0 makes it octal.

When you try to convert the number to decimal, try to put a 0x before it, so it's not mistaken for an octal number.

Comment: From what I know 0x isnt valid for certain canvas elements, I know its fine for pixi, but for normal canvas?

Or are you saying make the string an 0x? and the convert to decimal?

Comment: Adding 16 as the radix to parseInt he is explicitly saying the number is hexadecimal

Comment: @factordog just do `parseInt("0x" + yourColor, 16)`

Comment: Okay but for example parseInt("0x00aaa4", 16); will still return 43684 which will still leave it throwing an invalid colour value

Comment: what are valid color values for pixijs?

Comment: from my understanding its type number 0x?????? or a decimal colour value of 7+ numbers. From what I have read it cant take a #?????? or a rgb colour value. Has to be a number

Comment: Okay so I have taken your method, and then to accomodate for standard canvas I am using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

This allows me to then change the number value to a valid canvas value with correct hex if I need it. Most of my project is using Pixi which is why majority of it will be a number colour. So now I will use decimalToHex(d, padding) which is an answer further down and this will create a valid hex value for canvas