# How does subtracting zero turn a string into a hexadecimal number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, hex

After seeing [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107524/64507) answer in a Code Golf challenge, I found out about this:

```js
   console.log("0x" + "e" - 0); // 14
```

How does it happen?

Comment: -0 casts the string into the number - like "14"-0 would

Comment: Have a look at this for clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Comment: console.log(0xe) // results 14