# why javascript automatically converts hexadecimal value into decimal when assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, hex, decimal, type-conversion

I am trying to store some data in hexadecimal format to a variable in JavaScript and read the data in same format. When I tried assigning a variable to hexadecimal value and display it, I got as decimal value equivalent to hexadecimal.

```
var a = 0x0F;
WScript.Echo("a = "+a);
```

I got as `a = 15` instead of `a = 0x0F`. Why is this happening? Is it possible to get the value in hexadecimal format itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Comment: `0x0F`, `0o17` and `0b1111` are merely different ways of writing 15. You could do `(15).toString(16)`.

Comment: Hexadecimal is a notation, not a format. If you want to output a number in a base other than `10`, use `.toString` with the desired radix/base. If you want to store bytes, _Number_ probably isn't the best solution for you, look at [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

Answer (score 0):

`hexadecimal` type does not exist in `javascript`.

There's only a few types (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures):

- number
- string
- Object
- ...

What you are doing is a `number` assignment with an `hexadecimal` value.

But, `a` is a number so, it's normal representation is `decimal` form.

To have the `hexadecimal` value (as `string`) of your `decimal` `number`, you can take a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805/5119765