# cast long string to number using parseInt in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to cast this id `59aa94878d08a20758deed83` to number, I first tried without argument, I only got 59.

```js
var x=parseInt('59aa94878d08a20758deed83', 24);
console.log(x);
```

above won't return 59aa94878d08a20758deed83 in number?

Comment: Do you want to convert an *hexadecimal* number to a *decimal* number?

Comment: Do you mean from hexadecimal to decimal? Try `parseInt('59aa94878d08a20758deed83', 16);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado what do you mean by that? I just want the id in exact charactor but in number.

Comment: Well, I just give up...

Comment: That number is too big to fit in any numeric data type.

Comment: `Number` types in javascript cannot contain any alpha characters, only numbers. Unless you are trying to *convert* a hexadecimal or other type of number, your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just use correct radix. If it is real hexadecimal number, use radix 16, not 24...

```js
console.log(parseInt('59aa94878d08a20758deed83', 16))
```

Comment: how u know is 16?

Comment: I got this answer `2.7750384674146666e+28` is this correct?

Comment: I dont know. It must know author. It just seems like hexadecimal number, so I convert it from hexa to decimal. I have no idea whether it is correct or not.