# Convert float to 32bit hex string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, hex

I have a float value representing GPS coordinates and I liked to convert it to a 32bit hex string.

I tried every solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript) but everytime, the result is not what I am expecting.

For example, most of the 'ToHex' functions :

```
var lat = 45.839152;
console.log(ToHex(lat));
```

returns me `2d.56d0b30b5aa8`

but I am expecting `42355b43` for result as [most](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/) converters returns

do you know how I could get `42355b43` as a result in JavaScript ?

Thank you !

Comment: For starters, JavaScript numbers are 64-bit values, not 32.

Comment: Ok but i need a 32bits hex value, i van truncate it i suppose ?

Comment: I made float to hex string and hex string to float converter functions, and I get 0x42375b4a for 45.839152. I get this same result using other folks functions as well, such as https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html and https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/ If there's any interest I can place my javascript functions online, they are not obfuscated/minified like the other solutions so you can see how it works.

Comment: BTW the hex value you've provided translates to 45.3391227722168.

Comment: For decimal to float see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57803/1066234

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could take the [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) object with an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).

Then set the value as float 32 and read the view as unsigned  integer 8 bit for the values.

```js
const getHex = i => ('00' + i.toString(16)).slice(-2);

var view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4)),
    result;

view.setFloat32(0, 45.839152);

result = Array
    .apply(null, { length: 4 })
    .map((_, i) => getHex(view.getUint8(i)))
    .join('');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally decide to code my own function. I post it here so it could help people :

```
function ToHex(d) {

    var sign = "0";

    if(d<0.0){
        sign = "1";
        d = -d;
    }

    var mantissa = parseFloat(d).toString(2);

    var exponent = 0;

    if(mantissa.substr(0,1) === "0"){
        exponent = mantissa.indexOf('.') - mantissa.indexOf('1') + 127;
    }
    else{
        exponent = mantissa.indexOf('.') - 1 + 127;
    }

    mantissa = mantissa.replace(".", "");
    mantissa = mantissa.substr(mantissa.indexOf('1')+1);

    if(mantissa.length>23){
        mantissa = mantissa.substr(0,23);
    }
    else{
        while(mantissa.length<23){
            mantissa = mantissa +"0";
        }
    }

    var exp = parseFloat(exponent).toString(2);

    while(exp.length<8){
        exp = "0" + exp;
    }

    var numberFull = sign + exp + mantissa;

    return parseInt(numberFull, 2).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: If you pass it "0" it will return 3f800000 instead of zero, and if you pass 1999 it will return 3ef9e000 instead of 44f9e000, something doesnt seem quite right