# js how to parse HEX properly / fffd

Tags: javascript, hex

Having a problem here. I recieve data from hardware as HEX numbers. I use this to make them into strings(it is intended):

```
arr.push(data.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))
```

It works well. For example I recieve 0x00 and this code correctly adds a '0' string to the array.

But there is a problem. JS automatically understands these codes as symbols. And when I try 0xAA or 0x80 I recieve FFFD. As I understand. it means that there is no such symbol in utf-8.

How do I make js understand my data as hex-numbers, but not as symbol codes?

Edit: I figured out that my problem was in my wrong way of using the library which recieved data from hardware.

Comment: you aren't showing any symbols, you are showing the hex code for bytes. take off the `.toString(16)` if you want raw chars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just [convert the Hex number to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

```
yourNumber = parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert hexadecimal to decimal you can use the next function:

```
parseInt(hexValue, 16)
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
data = '0XAA'
data1 = '0X80'
console.log( parseInt(data, 16))
console.log( parseInt(data1, 16))
```

Comment: can you give an example of your data

Comment: and the typeof that data

Comment: example of data: ��]�k���]

typeof: string

What I sent from hardware: 0xAA 0x81 0x5D 0x00 0xE8 0xBD 0x74 0x10 0x00 0x12

Comment: ��]�k���]  Thats want you log before you do any change? ``]`` in ascii is ``0x5D`` but ``0x00`` in ascii is equal to ``null`` not to ``k``. You need to find a different way to send your data from the hardware. � this will not give you any information. https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%5D%EF%BF%BDk%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out that my problem was in a library I used to recieve data