# 64bit Hex to Decimal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point

Need to convert 64bit hex to decimal in node, preferably without 3rd party lib.

Input:

```
Hex: 0x3fe2da2f8bdec5f4
Hex: 0x402A000000000000
```

Output

```
Dec: .589134
Dec: 13
```

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks Matt for the link, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this very easily in node.js without any libraries by using [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readdoublebe_offset):

```
const hex = '3fe2da2f8bdec5f4';
const result = Buffer.from( hex, 'hex' ).readDoubleBE( 0 );
console.log( result );
```

**WARNING:** The offset of `0` is not optional. Several versions of the node.js API docs show examples of not supplying an offset for most Buffer functions and it being treated as an offset of `0`, but due to a [bug in node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18208) versions `9.4.0`, `9.5.0`, `9.6.0`, `9.6.1`, and `9.7` you will get slightly incorrect results (EG. `13.000001912238076` instead of exactly `13`) if you do not specify an offset to `readDoubleBE` in those versions.

Comment: This one is really clean!

Comment: @UtkarshNarainSrivastava Note that I just tested this in a couple of node versions. In 10.4 I get the exact correct results, but in 9.4.0 I get some weird small errors. It seems like a bug in certain versions. EG. I get `13.000001912238076` for `402A000000000000` in node 9.4.0, even though that represents `13` exactly.

Comment: @UtkarshNarainSrivastava I found out it was a bug starting in exactly version 9.4.0 : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18208 . It works in `9.3` and older but the bug exists in `9.4.0`, `9.5.0`, `9.6.0`, `9.6.1`, and `9.7`. It is fixed in `9.8` and later. If you are using this for personal use and not using those version you can use this, but if you are making an npm package or something that needs to be compatible with various node versions you should not use this.

Comment: Oh good news, there is a very easy fix to make it work in all versions of node. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @UtkarshNarainSrivastava Updated with a fix for all versions. Just make sure to specify the offset `0` as an argument to readDoubleBE and it will work in all versions.

Comment: thanks for the update. I will make the relevant changes.

Answer (score 2):

For those trying to do this in client side javscript

```
// Split the array by bytes 
a = "3fe2da2f8bdec5f4"
b = a.match(/.{2}/g);

// Create byte array 
let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8)
let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)

// Populate array 
for(let i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = parseInt(b[i], 16);
}

// Convert and print 
let view = new DataView(buffer)
console.log(view.getFloat64(0, false));
```

Comment: DataView is undefined since this is a `node.js` question.

Comment: @UtkarshNarainSrivastava Not in node.js without a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-dataview). You tagged your question as `node.js`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Going to leave it here just in case someone is looking for a client side solution :-)

Comment: No problem, your answer combined with the library I linked in the above comment works in node.js too.