# from a decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone help me 
with this problem? from decimal to binary is already working, but I couldn't get it working from decimal to hexadecimal.

I have a problem with this code: var ant2 = som2 * (gewenstgetal / 4); the rest is working but i couldn't get that to work, it would be very helpfull if someone can help me

```js
function omzetten() {
  var invoer = document.getElementById('omzettenInvoer').value;
  var talstelselVan = document.getElementById('omvettenVan').value;
  var gewenstgetal = document.getElementById('gewenstgetal').value;
  var waarde = 1;
  var positie = invoer.length - 1;
  var som = 0;
  while (positie >= 0) {
    var cijfer = invoer.charAt(positie);
    var poswaarde;
    if (cijfer == "a") {
      poswaarde = 10 * waarde
    } else if (cijfer == "b") {
      poswaarde = 11 * waarde
    } else if (cijfer == "c") {
      poswaarde = 12 * waarde
    } else if (cijfer == "d") {
      poswaarde = 13 * waarde
    } else if (cijfer == "e") {
      poswaarde = 14 * waarde
    } else if (cijfer == "f") {
      poswaarde = 15 * waarde
    } else {
      poswaarde = cijfer * waarde;
    }
    som = som + poswaarde;
    positie--;
    waarde = waarde * talstelselVan;
    var som2 = som * gewenstgetal;
    var ant2 = som2 * (gewenstgetal / 4);

    document.getElementById('output1').value = som;
    document.getElementById('output2').value = ant2;

  }
}
```

```css
/*phone*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav {
    background-color: #10689A;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #calcie {
    margin-left: 19.5vw !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    border: solid grey;
    width: 50vw;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 40vw !important;
  }
  header {
    display: none;
  }
  #bobies {
    width: 20vw;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 40vw;
  }
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #10689A;
    color: black;
  }
  .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  #desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  #home {
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
  #logo {
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #welkomstekst {
    background-color: #10689A;
    width: 70vw;
    margin-left: 15vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    line-height: 1.9;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  #welkomstekst p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 10vh;
    margin-left: 28vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    background-color: #10689A;
    border-radius: 2em;
    margin-bottom: .9em;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie button {
    width: 32vw;
    height: 4vh;
    margin-left: 4vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  header {
    width: 86.5vw;
    margin-left: 30%;
  }
  footer {
    margin-top: 10vw;
  }
  #biggie {
    max-width: 2vw;
  }
}


/*Tablet*/

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  #phone {
    display: none;
  }
  #Navbar {
    background-color: #10689A;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 120px;
    min-width: : 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  #Navbar a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  #Navbar img {
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vw;
    Margin-top: -5px;
  }
  #calcie {
    margin-left: 37.5vw !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    border: solid grey;
    width: 14vw;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 10vw !important;
  }
  #desktop {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  #home {
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
  #logo {
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #welkomstekst {
    background-color: #10689A;
    width: 50vw;
    margin-left: 25vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 4vh;
    line-height: 1.9;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  #welkomstekst p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2vw;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 10vh;
    margin-left: 42vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    background-color: #10689A;
    border-radius: 2em;
    margin-bottom: .9em;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie button {
    width: 11vw;
    height: 4vh;
    margin-left: 2.0vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  header {
    width: 86.5vw;
    margin-left: 30%;
  }
  footer {
    margin-top: 10vw;
  }
  #biggie {
    max-width: 2vw;
  }
}


/*Desktop*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1250px) {
  #phone {
    display: none;
  }
  #Navbar {
    background-color: #10689A;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 120px;
    min-width: : 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  #Navbar a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  #calcie {
    margin-left: 37.5vw !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    border: solid grey;
    width: 13vw;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 10vw !important;
  }
  #Navbar img {
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vw;
    Margin-top: -5px;
  }
  #desktop {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  #home {
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
  #logo {
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #welkomstekst {
    background-color: #10689A;
    width: 50vw;
    margin-left: 25vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 4vh;
    line-height: 1.9;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  #welkomstekst p {
    color: white;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #10689A;
    border-radius: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid-area: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'grid';
    margin-bottom: .9em;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie button {
    width: 7vw;
    height: 4vh;
    margin-left: 3.7vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  header {
    width: 46.5vw;
    margin-left: 30%;
  }
  footer {
    margin-top: 10vw;
  }
  #biggie {
    max-width: 2vw;
  }
  #buttie {
    min-width: 9vw;
    margin-left: 3vw !important;
  }
}


/*HD (High defenition)*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
  #bigmama1 {
    width: 20vw;
    height: 10vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #10689A;
    margin-left: 19vw;
    margin-top: 4vw;
    padding-left: 1.3vw;
  }
  #bigmama2 {
    width: 11vw;
    height: 10vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #10689A;
    margin-left: 24vw;
    margin-top: 20vw;
  }
  #id1 {
    margin-left: 22vw;
    margin-top: 2vw;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #nassi,
  #nabr[type="text"] {
    max-width: 2vw;
  }
  #id2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 26.5vw;
    margin-top: 18vw;
  }
  #output1 {
    margin-top: .5vw;
    width: 17.1vw !important;
    text-align: center;
    height: 7vw;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #phone {
    display: none;
  }
  #Navbar {
    background-color: #10689A;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 120px;
    min-width: : 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  #Navbar a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  #calcie {
    margin-left: 24.5vw !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    border: solid grey;
    width: 9vw;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 7vw !important;
  }
  #Navbar img {
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5vw;
    Margin-top: -5px;
  }
  #desktop {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  #home {
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
  #logo {
    margin-top: 20%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #welkomstekst {
    background-color: #10689A;
    width: 50vw;
    margin-left: 25vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 4vh;
    line-height: 1.9;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  #welkomstekst p {
    color: white;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 8vh;
    background-color: #10689A;
    border-radius: 2em;
    display: grid;
    grid-area: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 'grid';
    margin-bottom: .9em;
  }
  #toekomstreferencie button {
    width: 7vw;
    height: 4vh;
    margin-left: 3.7vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    border-radius: 2em;
  }
  header {
    width: 46.5vw;
    margin-left: 36%;
  }
  footer {
    margin-top: 10vw;
  }
  #biggie {
    max-width: 2vw;
  }
  #buttie {
    min-width: 9vw;
    margin-left: 3vw !important;
  }
}

#bobie {
  width: 3vw !important;
}

.nav-item {
  padding-top: 1.4vw;
}

.dropdown {
  max-width: 10vw;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 1.7vw;
}

.Fibo {
  background-color: #10689A;
  width: 50vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  line-height: 1.9;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

#dReeksP {
  color: white;
}

#dReeksF {
  color: white;
}

#output2 {
  margin-left: 12.9vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="desktop">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs auto-fill">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html"><img id="bobie" src="IMG/calculatorlogo.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Rad van fortuin</a>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Shoot the pig</a>
        </li>
      </li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Rekenen
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Rekenpagina</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gevorderd rekenpagina</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">reeksen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Omrekenen</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>


<section id="phone">
  <img id="bobies" src="IMG/calculatorlogo.png">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="">Rekenpagina</a>
    <a href="">Gevordend Rekenpagina</a>
    <a href="">Reeksen</a>
    <a href="">Omrekenen</a>
    <a href="">Rad van fortuin</a>
    <a href="">Shoot the pig</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="minis">
  <div id="welkomstekst">
    <p>Welkom bij <strong>Math-mate m2</strong> hier kan je:<br> lekker <strong>rekenen met hexa</strong></br>
      eigen manier, heb je na het <strong>rekenen</strong></br>
      zin in wat ontspanning speel shoot the pig!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="toekomstreferencie"><button id="buttie" onclick="toggle_visibility('minis')" href="#slides" data-toggle="collapse">Hexa's</button></div>
<div class="collapse" id="slides">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 id="id1">Binair naar hexadecimaal</h3>
    <div id="bigmama1">
      <form>
        <input type="text" value "" id="omzettenInvoer" placeholder="Waarde" value="1010" />
        <input type="number" value "" id="omvettenVan" placeholder="tal" value="2" />
        <button type="button" id="arie" value "" name="-->" disabled>--></button>
        <input type="text" value "" id="gewenstgetal" placeholder="tal" />
        <button type="button" value="verzenden" onclick="omzetten()">Bereken</button></br>
        <input type="text" value "" id="output1" name="input" />
        <input type="text" value "" id="output2" name="input" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <h3 id="id2">Factorizer</h3>
    <div id="bigmama2">
      <form>
        <input type="text" value "" id="getalie" placeholder="Hier invullen" name="input" />
        <button type="button" value="verzenden" onclick="he()">Bereken</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <p> &copy; Ravi Breugom en Alexander wallaard</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Convert Decimal to Hex Thread ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Comment: You should fix your HTML too. You cannot have HTML outside the body tag and you have several extra tags. You can use w3org's validation to see what to fix

Comment: Thanks everyone :o