# Convert Google Contact ID to Hex to use in URL

Tags: javascript, python, hex, decimal

Google Contacts now (Jan 2019) issues a long (19 digit) decimal number id for each contact that you create.

Unfortunately, as discussed in this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101925/direct-url-to-a-particular-person-in-google-contacts/124777#124777) the ID cannot be put into a URL to view the contact easily, however if you convert this decimal number to Hex it can be put into the URL.

So the question is, how to convert
c2913347583522826972 
to
286E4A310F1EEADC

When I use the Decimal to Hex converter [here](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter) it gives me
286E4A310F1EEADC if I drop the c (2nd function below is a version of the sites code, but it does use PHP too maybe)

However trying the following functions in Javascript give me mixed results

The first one is from this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript) which is the closest, just 2 digits off

```js
function decimalToHexString(number)
{
number = parseFloat(number);
  if (number < 0)
  {
    number = 0xFFFFFFFF + number + 1;
  }

  return number.toString(16);
}

console.log(decimalToHexString('2913347583522826972'));
//output 286e4a310f1eea00

function convertDec(inp,outp) {
    var pd = '';
    
    var output ;
    var input = inp;
    
    for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var e=input[i].charCodeAt(0);var s = "";
    output+= e + pd;
}
return output;
}
//return 50574951515255535651535050565054575550
```

Love to know your thoughts on improving this process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the limit of digit size. You have to use arrays if you need to convert bigger digits.

You can use [hex2dec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hex2dec) npm package to convert between hex and dec.

```
>> converter.decToHex("2913347583522826972", { prefix: false }
//286e4a310f1eeadc
```

[Js example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-grlyks)

On python side, you can simply do

```
dec = 2913347583522826972
// Python implicitly handles prefix
hexa =  hex(dec)
print dec == int(hexa, 16)
// True
```

[Python example](http://tpcg.io/izjNom)

For more take a look at the following gist
https://gist.github.com/agirorn/0e740d012b620968225de58859ccef5c