# Store a hex HTML color as a numerical value conversion returns different color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried the solution is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805/5724889) but it doesn't seem to help me. I have to store a Hex color in to a number and be able to successfully convert it back to hex color

I have put a working code below

```js
hexToNum = () => {
  const orignalColor = '#00FF7B';
  const newStr = orignalColor.replace('#', '');
  document.querySelector('#num').value = parseInt(newStr, 16);;
}

NumToHex = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('#str');
  const num = el.value;
  const str1 = num.toString(16);
  console.log(str1);
  el.style.borderColor = '#' + str1;
  el.style.backgroundColor = '#' + str1;
}
```

```css
.color1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
  border-color: #00FF7B;
  background-color: #00FF7B;
}

.color2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
}
```

```html
<div class='color1'></div>

<br/>
<button onclick="hexToNum()">Get Numeric Value </button> <input type='text' id='num'>


<br/><br/><br/>
<div class='color2'></div>

<br/><br/>
<input type='text' id='str'>
<button onclick="NumToHex()">Set Color From Numeric Value </button>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? The javascript part or the presentation part? Do the console outputs meets your requirements?

Comment: @reporter both when i convert to num i get `65403` when I put `65403` into second input type text it returns the number back but not hex string console logs wrong output i should get `#00FF7B` back

Comment: Values in  input fields have datatype "String". Does parseInt() help you to convert a number into a hex string?

Comment: Nope that didnt work tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @reporter noticed earlier, `input` value is `string`.

So you have to convert it to `number` with `parseInt` or other method e.g.

```
const num = +el.value;
```

Then convert to hex and left pad the result with `0`:

```
const str1 = num.toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
```

See the snippet below:

```js
hexToNum = () => {
  const orignalColor = '#00FF7B';
  const newStr = orignalColor.replace('#', '');
  document.querySelector('#num').value = parseInt(newStr, 16);;
}

NumToHex = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('#str');
  const num = +el.value;
  const str1 = num.toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
  console.log(str1);
  const c2 = document.querySelector('.color2')
  c2.style.borderColor = '#' + str1;
  c2.style.backgroundColor = '#' + str1;
}
```

```css
.color1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
  border-color: #00FF7B;
  background-color: #00FF7B;
}

.color2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
}
```

```html
<div class='color1'></div>

<br/>
<button onclick="hexToNum()">Get Numeric Value </button> <input type='text' id='num'>


<br/><br/><br/>
<div class='color2'></div>

<br/><br/>
<input type='text' id='str'>
<button onclick="NumToHex()">Set Color From Numeric Value </button>
```

Hope it helps.