# Finding average of colors? - hexadecimal strings

Tags: javascript, average, arrow-functions

**INSTRUCTIONS**

Write a function that takes 2 colors as arguments and returns the average color.

- The parameters will be two 6-digit hexadecimal strings. This does not need to be validated.
- The return value should be a 6-digit hexadecimal string.
- The hexadecimal strings represent colors in RGB, much like in CSS.
- The average color is to be determined by taking the arithmetic mean for each component: red, green and blue.

**CODE**

```
 const avgColor = (str1, str2) => {
    return (str1 + str2) / 2
 }
```

**QUESTION**

Hexadecimal is something like this `0000ff` right?

I'm not sure what it means when I need to take the arithmetic mean for each component and lists 3 colors. How do you take an average of strings?

Comment: You don't take "an average of strings". You interpret each pair of digits has a number and then do a simple numeric average.

Comment: A hexidecimal value isn't a string, it's a [base-16 numeric value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Comment: @Pointy sorry, im not understanding. `You interpret each pair of digits has a number`?

Comment: (1) Use substring to get each pair of digits.  (2) Use `parseInt(v, 16)` to convert each pair of hex digits to a number.  (3) Average your numbers.  (4) Convert each R, G, and B number back to hex using `.toString(16)`

Comment: `The parameters will be two 6-digit hexadecimal strings`. So this means not 2 strings but 2 numbers?

Comment: @Amy thanks, I think I understand it now with the explanation below, the `strings` part confused me and didn't know about `ff` as a value and such

Comment: this sounds like homework

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plain JS function:

You have to split the hex string into it's three color components before converting them to calculate the mean:

```
function calcAvg(hex1,hex2) {

  //parsed into decimal from hex
  //for each color pair
let hexC11 = parseInt(hex1.slice(0,2), 16);  
let hexC12 = parseInt(hex1.slice(2,4), 16);
let hexC13 = parseInt(hex1.slice(4,6), 16);
let hexC21 = parseInt(hex2.slice(0,2), 16);
let hexC22 = parseInt(hex2.slice(2,4), 16);
let hexC23 = parseInt(hex2.slice(4,6), 16);

  //calculate mean for each color pair
let colorMean1 = (hexC11 + hexC21) / 2;
let colorMean2 = (hexC12 + hexC22) / 2;
let colorMean3 = (hexC13 + hexC23) / 2;

  //convert back to hex
let colorMean1Hex = colorMean1.toString(16);
let colorMean2Hex = colorMean2.toString(16);
let colorMean3Hex = colorMean3.toString(16);

  //pad hex if needed
if (colorMean1Hex.length == 1)
  colorMean1Hex = "0" + colorMean1Hex;
if (colorMean2Hex.length == 1)
  colorMean2Hex = "0" + colorMean2Hex;
if (colorMean3Hex.length == 1)
  colorMean3Hex = "0" + colorMean3Hex;

  //merge color pairs back into one hex color
let avgColor = colorMean1Hex +
    colorMean2Hex +
    colorMean3Hex;

  return avgColor;
}

let avg = calcAvg("999999","777777");
console.log(avg);
```

Comment: when i run this with an example, an answer returns as this `"7f.8007f.8"`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with this snippet:

```js
function avg(a,b){
  const regex=/^#?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})$/ //regular expression to parse string
  a=regex.exec(a).slice(1)  //create array from string 'a' using regex
  b=regex.exec(b).slice(1)  //create array from string 'b' using regex
  let output=''
  for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    const value=Math.floor(
       (
         parseInt(a[i],16) + //parse decimal from hexadecimal
         parseInt(b[i],16)   //parse decimal from hexadecimal
       )/2                   //perform averaging
     ).toString(16)          //convert back to hexadecimal
     output += (value.length<2?'0':'') + value //add leading zero if needed
  }
  return output
}
```

Comment: getting this error when i try 2 values. `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null`

Comment: Which values did you try?

Comment: `("0000ff", "ff0000")`

Comment: With small `f`s?

Comment: yeah just used the ending example from below

Comment: That's strange: I've just tried your values, and it worked fine!

Comment: your edit made it work, but now it's this `"#7f07f"`, is `#` a hexadecimal value?

Comment: Usually hexadecimal colors marked by `#` on the beginning, but if you don't need it, you can remove from here: `let output="#"`

Comment: but aren't these values 6 digits long? if we remove that, then it'll be 5 digits?

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate the average of a hexadecimal string value, you need to:

- Convert the hexadecimal string to integer (something similar to `parseInt('0000ff', 16)`)
- Split the color components
- Calculate the average value for each color component
- Reconstruct the final value from the color components
- Convert the result back to hexadecimal string (with padding), you can refer to this question [How to convert decimal to hexadecimal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-javascript) .

An example of full code snippet will be something similar to

```
const avgColor = (str1, str2) => {
    // Convert the hexadecimal string to integer
    const color1 = parseInt(str1, 16);
    const color2 = parseInt(str2, 16);

    let avgColor = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // Split the color components
        comp1 = (color1 >> (8 * i)) & 0xff;
        comp2 = (color2 >> (8 * i)) & 0xff;
        // Calculate the average value for each color component
        let v = parseInt((comp1 + comp2) / 2) << 8 * i;

        // Reconstruct the final value from the color components
        avgColor += parseInt((comp1 + comp2) / 2) << 8 * i;
    }

    return decimalToHex(avgColor, 6);
}

// Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-javascript
function decimalToHex(d, padding) {
    var hex = Number(d).toString(16);
    padding = typeof (padding) === "undefined" || padding === null ? padding = 2 : padding;

    while (hex.length < padding) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }

    return hex;
}

console.log(avgColor("0000ff", "ff0000"))
```

Comment: This won't work for it exactly, as they need to split the hex string into its three color components before calculating the average. "The average color is to be determined by taking the arithmetic mean for each component."

Comment: @HBlackorby Thanks for pointing it out! I have fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Hexadecimal is something like this 0000ff right?

Yes.

To elaborate, each two characters of the "hexadecimal string" represents a color in hexadecimal (16 numbers per digit), rather than decimal (10 numbers per digit). So the first two characters represent the Red value of the color, the second two characters represent the Green value of the color, and the last two characters represent the Blue value of the color. Combining these values results in the final color.

To further elaborate, the "ff" hexadecimal value equals 256 as a decimal value. Hexadecimal digits go from 0-9, then continue to a, b, c, d, e, and f, before wrapping around to 0 again, so a hexadecimal "0f" number, would equal 16 in decimal. A hexadecimal "10" number would equal 17 as a decimal value. Counting from 0 to 17 in hexadecimal would look like this:

"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "0a", "0b", "0c", "0d", "0f", "10".

Comment: brain fried for a second, I'll reboot and see if I understand this fully

Comment: @mph85 so like, if you were to take your example "0000ff". in decimal values, it would mean a red value of 0, a green value of 0, and a blue value of 256. This way of representing colors is referred to as RGB (red, green, blue). With 0-256 values for each component of an RGB value, you can create any color (essentially). using hexadecimal numbers instead of decimal numbers, means you can use 6 characters to represent any RGB color, instead of needing 9 characters to represent any RGB color (as you would using decimals).

Comment: gotcha, so what does it mean to take the arithmetic mean for each component? would blue just be `128`?

Comment: or do i need to convert to number and then average?

Comment: @mph85 yes, but teacher would likely be wanting you to turn it back into a hexidecimal string for your final answer. vanilla javascript has a way of converting hex to dec and vice versa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-javascript

Comment: @mph85 so likely, break the string into three parts, convert each part to decimal, average the decimal values, then convert back to hex parts, then combine into final string. there may be a way to create averages using hex numbers, but I am unsure. if so, you would be able to skip the conversion to decimal and back.

Comment: Got it, appreciate the explanation, I'll see what I can come up with with everyone's input.

Answer (score -1):

There is a jQuery plugin for this if you can use jQuery -

```
$.xcolor.average(color, color)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. I believe the hw just wanted a function written in vanilla JS, but I upvote for showing me a different way.