# Attempts to convert string to hex log string without encryption

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a text box which will give an output of a string in hex. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-javascript) which I got my current code from which I modified a bit, but when I logged it, instead of the string "486578", I got "Hex". Here is my code:

```js
function Hex() {
  var Hex = "Hex"
  Hex = Hex.toString('16');
  console.log(Hex)
}

Hex();
```

And no, I don't want something like encrypt.js. How would I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you could share what you tried we could be more helpful

Comment: It seems to me that you are printing the variable name instead of the value...

Comment: The question you've linked is about converting a *number* to hex. You're trying to convert a *string*...

Comment: Additionally your "expected output" isn't even hex, it's just the *decimal* ordinal values of the characters concatenated together...

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) but [`String.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString).

Your input is the string "Hex". This gets converted to a string "Hex". You should try to use a number, if you want to convert a number.

In order to get numbers, you have to encode your string.

```js
var encoded = new TextEncoder().encode("Hex");

var hex = Object.values(encoded).map(n => n.toString(16));

console.log (hex.join (' '));
```

Compare it with the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).