# Convert encoded string to decimal in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, photoshop-script

I omitted this earlier to avoid confusion. Written communication doesn't come easily to us all #actuallyautistic.

This is part of a larger script in Photoshop taken from [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-do-i-export-the-color-table-act-file-using-a-script/td-p/11081410?page=1)

I'm trying to extract the palette values in the image as hexadecimal colours or RGB values.

var msg = "";

```
for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    var bin = String.fromCharCode(table.charCodeAt(i), table.charCodeAt(256+i), table.charCodeAt(512+i))
    msg += bin.toString(2);
    // msg += (table.charCodeAt(i), table.charCodeAt(256+i), table.charCodeAt(512+i));
    // msg += "\n";
}
```

The version commented out collects the Blue data, but not the Red or Green. I don't know why.

`msg` is then written to a file. In Notepad it looks like this:

```
@@ `@ €` @ @¿©Ð´€€aà€@€  DDD
```

Which seems meaningless. In Sublime Text I can see it's a series of hex numbers.

```
0000 0020 4040 0060 4020 8060 0040 2040
bf7f a9d0 b480 8061 e080 4080 2000 4444
4420 2020 0000...
```

In pure Javascript (or ECMA rather), how can I convert the former to the latter?

Comment: This very much depends on how you get the text into Javascript in the first place. Where does it come from, how might it be pre-interpreted before your Javascript gets its hands on it?

Comment: This is part of a much more complicated chain. Currently there's no easy method to extract the colours from an index colour image in Photoshop as shown [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/how-do-i-export-the-color-table-act-file-using-a-script/td-p/11081410?page=1) The file is binary encoded `tmp_file.encoding = "BINARY";`

Comment: Instead of writing them out as an act I want to write them out as text (hex/RGB) - that's the plan.

Comment: Not fully sure but this might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-javascript

Comment: So you're trying to read a binary file (an image?) and extract its colours? Then anything with Notepad and text encoding is a red herring, forget about that. Presumably you'd try to use some library which can read out that colour information first and foremost. And if/how that's possible very much depends on the context. Browser? Node? Photoshop?

Comment: This is all in Photoshop. incidentally, when alerting the string within photoshop it reads the same as in notepad.

Comment: Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64820054/edit) your question with these details. You want colour information, and you're running in Photoshop. Those are rather crucial details.