# How can I get RGB or HEX or RGBA values from interpolateColor using React Native Reanimated?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'd like to store and RGB value using setState or something like that. InterpolateColor() currently returns a big number. Here's my repo:
https://github.com/duether/react-native-color-picker

Comment: Were you able to find a way?

Comment: @purewatashi21 unfortunately.. no :(

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for converting interpolated color to hex, I found the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/697841/14332782 so I did the following:

```
 const decimalToHexString = (number: any) => {
    if (number < 0) {
      number = 0xffffffff + number + 1;
    }
    setColor(number.toString(16).substring(2, 8));
  };
```

> then run `runOnJS(decimalToHexString)(interpolatedColor);`