# Who can convert this 10₂ to decimal

Tags: typescript

Decimal and binary conversion.

Decimal and binary conversion. 2.
I just wanna know how to convert binary to decimals, and decimals to binary, or hexadecimals to decimals, that's all I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert decimal to hexadecimal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`parseInt(num, radix)` global method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [`Number.prototype.toString(radix)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to do that, sample below:

```js
console.log(parseInt('ff', 16)); // Hex to decimal
console.log((128).toString(16)); // Decimal to hex
```